# How to avoid this kind of repetition

Tags: c++, c++11, dry

I have code similar to this:

```
#include <string>

class A{
public:
    std::string &get(){
        return s;
    }

    const std::string &get() const{
        return s;
    }

    std::string &get_def(std::string &def){
        return ! s.empty() ? s : def;
    }

    // I know this might return temporary
    const std::string &get_def(const std::string &def) const{
        return ! s.empty() ? s : def;
    }

private:
    std::string s = "Hello";
};
```

I am wondering is there easy way to avoid code repetition in get() functions?

Comment: annoying right? I'm tempted to create a macro with const or nothing, but it's not very C++-like.

Comment: I don't even have a way to reuse the functions without const_cast or make s to be mutable

Comment: Ew @ right-aligned ampersands ;)

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2150192/560648? Though that Q is a bit crap...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - correct answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-funct

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[wandbox example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pTQ69s3aEh0ysFab)

Alternative to `const_cast`: creating a `static` template function that takes `*this` as a reference:

```
class A
{
private:
    template <typename TSelf, typename TStr>
    static auto& get_def_impl(TSelf& self, TStr& def)
    {
        return !self.s.empty() ? self.s : def;
    }

public:
    auto& get_def(std::string& str)
    {
        return get_def_impl(*this, str);
    }

    const auto& get_def(const std::string& str) const
    {
        return get_def_impl(*this, str);
    }
};
```

This works because of [template argument deduction rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) - in short, `TSelf` will accept both `const` and non-`const` references.

If you need to access members of `this` inside `get_def_impl`, use `self.member`.

Additionally,  you can use `std::conditional` or similar facilities inside `get_def_impl` to do different things depending on the `const`-ness of `TSelf`. You can also use a forwarding reference *(`TSelf&&`)* and handle the case where `this` is being moved thanks to [ref-qualifiers](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/ref-qualifiers/) and [perfect-forwarding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward).

Comment: Why would you ever move `*this` (which I presume is what you meant)?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: what I meant was handling cases where `get_def` is being called from a temporary `A` instance (`auto get_def(/*...*/) && { /*...*/ }`). You may need to move some members of `A` inside `get_def_impl` in that case

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: [this is very contrived](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gSjoHxOerggYsePV) and there's probably a much better way of doing this, but let's assume that you have two `static` repetition helpers and two sets of ref-qualified accessors. If I call `A{}.get()` and I want **both** `&&`-qualified versions of the accessors to be called without any code repetition or unnecessary moves I need to deal with the *rvalueness* of `*this` in the `static` helpers. If you can simplify this to not use forwarding-references for `*this`, that would be great.

Comment: `*this` is always an _lvalue_. Doesn't matter that it represents a temporary object. But that's precisely why you need the `std::move` so okay :)

Answer (score 1):

In some use cases you could also make use of non-member function template like:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template <class U, class R = std::conditional_t<std::is_const<U>::value, std::string const&, std::string& >>
R get(U &u) {
   return u.s;
}

template <class U, class R = std::conditional_t<std::is_const<U>::value, std::string const&, std::string& >>
R get_def(U &u, typename std::remove_reference<R>::type& def) {
   return u.s.empty() ? u.s : def;
}

struct S {
   template <class U, class R>
   friend R get(U &);
   template <class U, class R>
   friend R get_def(U &, typename std::remove_reference<R>::type&);
private:
   std::string s;
};

int main() {
   S s;
   get(s) = "abc";
   //get(static_cast<const S &>(s)) = "abc"; // error: passing ‘const std::basic_string<char>’ as ‘this’...
   std::string s2 = get(static_cast<const S&>(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't answer the question directly, but I'd usually lean towards a const getter + non const setter - that way your class will get notified when the string is changed and can act on it (in the future) if needed - without having to go through and change everything that uses it.

Comment: Not always appropriate. For example, imagine if `std::vector::operator[]` were `const`-only and you had to pass in new values wholesale via a setter.

Comment: I agree - not always; it's really a java/c# way of thinking I'll admit, but it has it's advantages in places.