# Best practice for avoiding code duplication while implementing iterator and const_iterator classes

Tags: c++, constants, class-design, code-duplication

What are the best practices to avoid code duplication when implementing class pairs such as `iterator` and `const_iterator` or similar?

- Does one usually implement iterator in terms of const_iterator using lots of const_casts?
- Does one employ some sort of traits class and end up defining both iterator and const_iterator as different instantiations of a common template?

This seems like a common enough problem to have a canonical solution but I have failed to find any articles dedicated to that.

Comment: Sorry, too broad. Many different approaches. Inheritance. Templates. There is no universally agreed-upon "best practice". Each individual case varies.

Comment: I prefer a template class parametrized by `value_type`, `pointer_type`, `reference_type`. For example:  `template <typename PType> class CustomIterator {};`
`typedef CustomIterator<MyClass*> iterator_type;`
`typedef CustomIterator<const MyClass*> const_iterator_type;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150192/how-to-avoid-code-duplication-implementing-const-and-non-const-iterators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any experience with implementing iterators, although I think this is similar to other projects. Refactor common code, etc.

Looking at [GNU libstdc++'s](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/) implementation of [`std::vector::iterator`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01523_source.html#l00231)

```
#include <bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h>
// ...
template ... class vector : ... {
    typedef __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pointer, vector> iterator;
    typedef __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const_pointer, vector> const_iterator;
};
```