# How do I specify a pointer to an overloaded function?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to pass an overloaded function to the `std::for_each()` algorithm. For example,

```
class A {
    void f(char c);
    void f(int i);

    void scan(const std::string& s) {
        std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), f);
    }
};
```

I'd expect the compiler to resolve `f()` by the iterator type. Apparently, it (GCC 4.1.2) doesn't do it. So, how can I specify which `f()` I want?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You can use `static_cast<>()` to specify which `f` to use according to the function signature implied by the function pointer type:

```
// Uses the void f(char c); overload
std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), static_cast<void (*)(char)>(&f));
// Uses the void f(int i); overload
std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), static_cast<void (*)(int)>(&f));
```

Or, you can also do this:

```
// The compiler will figure out which f to use according to
// the function pointer declaration.
void (*fpc)(char) = &f;
std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), fpc); // Uses the void f(char c); overload
void (*fpi)(int) = &f;
std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), fpi); // Uses the void f(int i); overload
```

If `f` is a member function, then you need to use [`mem_fun`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/mem_fun/), or for your case, use [the solution presented in this Dr. Dobb's article](http://www.drdobbs.com/184401746).

Comment: The second method looks very unsafe, is it not?

Comment: thanks! I still have a problem, though, probably due to the fact that `f()` is a member of a class (see the edited example above)

Comment: @the_drow: How so? The function pointer assignment only works if there is an overload that matches the function signature implied by the function pointer declaration.

Comment: @the_drow: The second method is actually much safer, if one of the overloads goes away the first method silently gives undefined behavior, while the second catches the problem at compile time.

Comment: @BenVoigt Hmm, I tested this on vs2010 and couldn't find a case where the static_cast wouldn't catch the problem at compile time.  It gave a C2440 with "None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type".  Can you clarify?

Comment: @Nathan: It's possible I was thinking of `reinterpret_cast`.  Most often I see C-style casts used for this.  My rule is just that casts on function pointers are dangerous and unnecessary (as the second code snippet shows, an implicit conversion exists).

Comment: I also recommend typedefs, they clarify function pointers significantly.

Comment: For member functions: `std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), static_cast<void (A::*)(char)>(&A::f));`

Comment: @sjwarner `std::for_each` won't accept pointer to member function.

Comment: `mem_fun` is deprecated and should be replaced by `mem_fn`

Answer (score 40):

Lambdas to the rescue! (note: C++11 required)

```cpp
std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [&](char a){ return f(a); });
```

Or using decltype for the lambda parameter:

```cpp
std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [&](decltype(*s.begin()) a){ return f(a); });
```

With polymorphic lambdas (C++14):

```cpp
std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [&](auto a){ return f(a); });
```

Or disambiguate by removing overloading (only works for free functions):

```cpp
void f_c(char i)
{
    return f(i);
}
    
void scan(const std::string& s)
{
    std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), f_c);
}
```

Comment: Hurray for lambdas!  Indeed, an excellent solution to the overload resolution problem.  (I thought of this also, but decided to leave it out of my answer so as not to muddy the waters.)

Comment: More code for the same result. I think that's not what the lambdas were made for.

Comment: @TomášZato The difference is that this answer works, and the accepted one doesn't (for the example posted by OP - you also need to use `mem_fn` and `bind`, which, BTW. are also C++11). Also, if we want to get really pedantic `[&](char a){ return f(a); }` is 28 characters, and `static_cast<void (A::*)(char)>(&f)` is 35 characters.

Comment: @TomášZato There you go http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1faad53c4de6c233 not sure how to make this more clear

Answer (score 25):

#### Why doesn't it work

> I'd expect the compiler to resolve `f()` by the iterator type. Apparently, it (gcc 4.1.2) doesn't do it.

It'd be great if that were the case! However, `for_each` is a function template, declared as:

```
template <class InputIterator, class UnaryFunction>
UnaryFunction for_each(InputIterator, InputIterator, UnaryFunction );
```

Template deduction needs to select a type for `UnaryFunction` at the point of the call. But `f` doesn't have a specific type - it's an overloaded function, there are many `f`s each with different types. There is no current way for `for_each` to aid the template deduction process by stating which `f` it wants, so template deduction simply fails. In order to have the template deduction succeed, you need to do more work on the call site.

#### Generic solution to fixing it

Hopping in here a few years and C++14 later. Rather than use a `static_cast` (which would allow template deduction to succeed by "fixing" which `f` we want to use, but requires you to manually do overload resolution to "fix" the correct one), we want to make the compiler work for us. We want to call `f` on some args. In the most generic way possible, that's:

```
[&](auto&&... args) -> decltype(auto) { return f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); }
```

That's a lot to type, but this sort of problem comes up annoyingly frequently, so we can just wrap that in a macro (sigh):

```
#define AS_LAMBDA(func) [&](auto&&... args) -> decltype(func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...)) { return func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); }
```

and then just use it:

```
void scan(const std::string& s) {
    std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), AS_LAMBDA(f));
}
```

This will do exactly what you wish the compiler did - perform overload resolution on the name `f` itself and just do the right thing. This will work regardless of whether `f` is  a free function or a member function.

Comment: Since it took me a second, for member functions you can use `std::mem_fn`.

Comment: @Kostas No, you can't use `std::mem_fn` if the member function is overloaded (which is what the question is asking for).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you please help illustrate if this is at all possible with a method, which also has a private overload?

Answer (score 6):

The problem here seems to be not *overload resolution* but in fact *template parameter deduction*.  While the [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2942442/1193893) from @In silico will solve an ambiguous overloading problem in general, it seems the best fix when dealing with `std::for_each` (or similar) is to **explicitly specify its template parameters**:

```
// Simplified to use free functions instead of class members.

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void f( char c )
{
  std::cout << c << std::endl;
}

void f( int i )
{
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

void scan( std::string const& s )
{
  // The problem:
  //   error C2914: 'std::for_each' : cannot deduce template argument as function argument is ambiguous
  // std::for_each( s.begin(), s.end(), f );

  // Excellent solution from @In silico (see other answer):
  //   Declare a pointer of the desired type; overload resolution occurs at time of assignment
  void (*fpc)(char) = f;
  std::for_each( s.begin(), s.end(), fpc );
  void (*fpi)(int)  = f;
  std::for_each( s.begin(), s.end(), fpi );

  // Explicit specification (first attempt):
  //   Specify template parameters to std::for_each
  std::for_each< std::string::const_iterator, void(*)(char) >( s.begin(), s.end(), f );
  std::for_each< std::string::const_iterator, void(*)(int)  >( s.begin(), s.end(), f );

  // Explicit specification (improved):
  //   Let the first template parameter be derived; specify only the function type
  std::for_each< decltype( s.begin() ), void(*)(char) >( s.begin(), s.end(), f );
  std::for_each< decltype( s.begin() ), void(*)(int)  >( s.begin(), s.end(), f );
}

void main()
{
  scan( "Test" );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind using C++11, here's a clever helper that is similar to (but less ugly than) the static cast:

```
template<class... Args, class T, class R>
auto resolve(R (T::*m)(Args...)) -> decltype(m)
{ return m; }

template<class T, class R>
auto resolve(R (T::*m)(void)) -> decltype(m)
{ return m; }
```

(Works for member functions; should be obvious how to modify it to work for freestanding functions, and you *should* be able to provide both versions and the compiler will select the right one for you.)

With thanks to Miro Knejp for suggesting: see also https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/rLVGeGUXsK0/IGj9dKmSyx4J.

Comment: OP's problem is not being able to pass an overloaded name into a function template, and your solution involves passing an overloaded name into a function template? This is just exactly the same problem.

Comment: @Barry Not the same problem. Template argument deduction succeeds in this case. [It works](http://ideone.com/8Dil5x) (with a few minor tweaks).

Comment: @Oktalist Because you're providing `R`, it's not deduced. There's also no mention of that in this answer.

Comment: @Barry I'm not providing `R`, I'm providing `Args`. `R` and `T` are deduced. It's true the answer could be improved. (There is no `T` in my example though, because it's not a pointer-to-member, because that wouldn't work with `std::for_each`.)

Comment: I upvoted this earlier. It's a nice approach, however I now discover it doesn't generalize. E.g., `resolve<>` won't resolve a zero-argument function, and so on. (For an approach that _does_ work, check out pybind11's `overload_cast`.)

Answer (score 5):

Not to answer your question, but am I the only one that finds

```
for ( int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++ ) {
   f( s[i] );
}
```

both simpler and shorter than the `for_each` alternative suggested by in silico in this case?

Comment: probably, but it's boring :) also, if I want to use iterator to avoid the [] operator, this becomes longer...

Comment: @Davka Boring is what we want. Also, iterators are typically no faster (may be slower) than using op[, if that is your concern.

Comment: Algorithms should be preferred to for loops, since they're less error prone and can have better opportunities for optimisation.  There's an article on that somewhere... here it is: http://www.drdobbs.com/184401446

Comment: If you don't have lambdas and auto, iterators can have some serious semantic and syntactic overhead that is just not worth it. If the OP had used a numeric loop, he'd have saved himself time.

Comment: @Ashley Until I see some objective stats on the "less error prone"  I see no need to believe it. And Meyers in the article appears to talking about loops that use iterators - I'm talking about the efficiency of loops that DON'T use iterators - my own benchmarks tend to suggest that these are marginally faster when optimised - certainly no slower.

Comment: Here am I, I also find your solution much better.

Comment: -1: At least write the damn thing correctly ! Use the correct type (size_t) and cache the size: `for(size_t i=0,n=s.size();i<n;++i){f(s[i]);}` or use a range base for loop: `for(const auto&item:s){f(item);}`

Comment: This works only for iteration over a collection with an `operator[]` implementation which itself works with integers in the range [0, size) for some known size.  There are countless uses for lambdas which are not this.  In fact, countless uses where iterators and range-based `for` loops won't cut it (e.g. traversal of trees, traversal of heterogeneous collections with a bounded set of contained types (the "visitor pattern"), etc.)