# "unresolved overloaded function type" with static function in std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, std-function

I am getting an "unresolved overloaded function type" error when trying to pass an overloaded static function to an `std::function`.

I am aware of similar questions, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220452/getting-the-address-of-an-overloaded-static-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942426/how-to-specify-a-pointer-to-an-overloaded-function). However, even though the answers there work for getting the address of the right function into a function pointer, they fail with `std::function`. Here is my MWE:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct ClassA {
  static std::string DoCompress(const std::string& s) { return s; }
  static std::string DoCompress(const char* c, size_t s) { return std::string(c, s); }
};

void hello(std::function<std::string(const char*, size_t)> f) {
  std::string h = "hello";
  std::cout << f(h.data(), h.size()) << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::string (*fff) (const char*, size_t) = &ClassA::DoCompress;
  hello(fff);
  hello(static_cast<std::string(const char*, size_t)>(&ClassA::DoCompress));
}
```

Could someone explain why the `static_cast` doesn't work when the implicit one does?

Comment: _"... when the implicit one does?"_ That it compiles without error, is because it will cast regardless of the involved types. It's just like applying `reinterpret_cast<>`.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ True, but in my case, not even `reinterpret_cast` worked. Knowing what my mistake was, of course, makes it obvious why. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't cast to a *function type*. You probably meant to cast to a *pointer type*:

```
hello(static_cast<std::string(*)(const char*, size_t)>(&ClassA::DoCompress));
//                           ^^^
```

Comment: I see, so the right answers is "because I am stupid". :) Just a short follow-up question then: what are function types good for then? Only to be used as template parameters to e.g. `std::function`?

Comment: @DavidNemeskey And for creating pointers and references to them. E.g. `using FuncType = double (int, char); FuncType *f = &myFunc;`

Comment: @DavidNemeskey a function type is valid in [some contexts](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91b7611f93fc0c3f) unrelated to meta-programming