# C++ method as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, methods, parameters

I have a function type, from SpiderMonkey:

```
typedef bool (* JSNative)(JSContext* cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value* vp);
```

I need to construct an array of structures containing references to methods of this type.

I need to make these using function templates with parameters as references to methods of some classes.

I've managed to pass class data members pointers to these templates:

```
template<typename PrivateType> class jsObjectDataClass : public jsBaseDataClass<PrivateType>
{
public:

template <typename pT, typename jspT, pT PrivateType::*Property> static bool GetProperty(JSContext *cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value *vp)
{
...
PrivateType* data = ...; // initialize here an object having the Property data member
...
data->*Property; // use here the Property data member of an object called 'data'
...
}
```

and use it as:

```
const JSPropertySpec jsAIDocumentMiPrintRecord::fProperties[] = {
JS_PSGS("paperRect", (jsAIDocumentMiPrintRecord::GetProperty<AIRect, jsAIRect, &AIDocumentMiPrintRecord::paperRect>), (jsAIDocumentMiPrintRecord::SetProperty<AIRect, jsAIRect, &AIDocumentMiPrintRecord::paperRect>), JSPROP_PERMANENT | JSPROP_ENUMERATE),
...
JS_PS_END
};
```

It works to pass and get set object's data members.

To resume, the following:

```
template <typename pT, typename jspT, pT PrivateType::*Property> static bool GetProperty(JSContext *cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value *vp)
```

becomes:

```
jsAIDocumentMiPrintRecord::GetProperty<AIRect, jsAIRect, &AIDocumentMiPrintRecord::paperRect>(JSContext *cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value *vp)
```

is matched with:

```
typedef bool (* JSNative)(JSContext* cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value* vp);
```

I need a similar thing for a limited type of methods instead of data members(well, "limited" is not "a few"), meaning some method like:

```
template <typename jsType, typename PrivateType, AIErr (SuiteType::*SuiteGetMethod)(PrivateType&)> static bool GetMethod(JSContext *cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value *vp)
    {
...

SuiteType* fSuite = ...; init the object that contains the method to be called

AIErr aiErr = kNoErr;

            PrivateType pt;

            if (fSuite)
                aiErr = fSuite->*SuiteGetMethod(pt); // call here the method of specific type
...
}
```

... but it seems that this is not matched as:

```
typedef bool (* JSNative)(JSContext* cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value* vp);
```

to be used as:

```
const JSFunctionSpec jsAIDocumentSuite::fFunctions[] = {
JS_FN("GetDocumentFileSpecification", (jsAIDocumentSuite::GetMethod<jsAIFilePath, ai::FilePath, &AIDocumentSuite::GetDocumentFileSpecification>), 1, 0),
...
    JS_FS_END
};
```

where we have:

```
struct AIDocumentSuite {

    /** Retrieves the file specification for the current document.
            @param file [out] A buffer in which to return the file specification.
        */
    AIAPI AIErr (*GetDocumentFileSpecification) ( ai::FilePath &file );
...
};
```

What is the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: The error is: `Error C2440 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'JSNative'`

Comment: Try passing that member functions by reference, and get it's reference from std::mem_fun_ref ( eg. `std::mem_fun_ref(&myClass::myMethod)` )

Comment: Also, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852738/c-pointers-to-overloaded-functions).

Comment: I don't know what to say, it is about data members of a structure, which are pointers to functions. I can't make it work or I misunderstand the article...

Comment: You need to get rid of the noise in the above question.  Reduce it down to a sscce -- or mcve.  See this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- read it and give it a try.  The goal is to remove *EVERYTHING* that doesn't lead directly to your compile error.  And produce a short bit of code that generates it.  Even down to `"GetDocumentFileSpecification"` is whose value *clearly* doesn't cause the error.  Delete all the garbage.  No `...`, just code that compiles and generates your error.  But is minimal.  And yes, this is work.

Comment: Right. I have found a solution regarding the function signature: `template <typename jsType, typename PrivateType, AIErr(*SuiteType::*SuiteGetMethod)(PrivateType&)> static bool GetMethod(JSContext *cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value *vp)`. Now, I need to find the way to call that method.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution is...

... the template function and the call to the method are:

```
template <typename jsType, typename PrivateType, AIErr(*SuiteType::*SuiteGetMethod)(PrivateType&)> static bool GetMethod(JSContext *cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value *vp)
{
...
SuiteType* fSuite = ...; init the object that contains the method to be called

AIErr aiErr = kNoErr;

PrivateType pt;

if (fSuite)
    aiErr = (fSuite->*SuiteGetMethod)(pt); // call here the method of specific type
...
}
```