# Use Delegate C#

Tags: c#, delegates

I am new to delegates , I would like to know the diference between the first code and second code

I have a class

```
public class FindPerson
{
    public int Age;
    public string Name;
    public string Surname;

    public FindPerson(string name, string surname, int age)
    {
        this.Age = age;
        this.Surname = surname;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Name=" + this.Name + " Surname=" + this.Surname + ", Age=" + this.Age.ToString();
    }
}
```

First code

```
public void Test2()
{
    List<FindPerson> lst = new List<FindPerson>();

    lst.Add(new FindPerson("Alex","Sweit",31));
    lst.Add(new FindPerson("Alex2", "Sweit", 30));
    lst.Add(new FindPerson("Alex3", "Sweit", 34));

    FindPerson iam = lst.Find(a => a.Name.Equals("Alex"));
}
```

Second code:

```
public void Test2()
{
    List<FindPerson> lst = new List<FindPerson>();

    lst.Add(new FindPerson("Alex","Sweit",31));
    lst.Add(new FindPerson("Alex2", "Sweit", 30));
    lst.Add(new FindPerson("Alex3", "Sweit", 34));

    FindPerson iam2 = lst.Find(new Predicate<FindPerson>(delegate(FindPerson find)
    {
        return find.Name.Equals("Alex");
    }));
}
```

I am learning to use delegates but it is not clear.

Comment: The first is easier to type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's essentially the same thing.

The `delegate() { }` syntax was introduced in C# 2.0, while the lambda syntax was introduced in C# 3.0. They were designed with different goals in mind, but serve the same purpose.

Let me quote [Eric Lippert](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2425867) (it's #7 on his top 10 worst C# features):

> I think all concerned would agree that it's unfortunate to have two inconsistent syntaxes for what is basically the same thing. C# is stuck with it, though, because existing C# 2.0 code still uses the old syntax.
>
> The "heaviness" of the C# 2.0 syntax was seen at the time as a benefit. The thought was that users might be confused by this new feature of nested methods, and the design team wanted a clear keyword in there calling out that a nested method was being converted to a delegate. No one could see into the future to know that a much lighter-weight syntax would be needed in a couple of years.

You won't see the `delegate() { }` syntax being used much in new code nowadays, as virtually everyone prefers the lighter lambda `=>` syntax.

`new Predicate<FindPerson>` just types the delegate explicitly and isn't needed anymore. It used to be mandatory in C# 1 IIRC. It can be inferred in most cases so it can be omitted (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31866280/3764814) for an example case when it's needed).

Its existence is due to the fact that a lambda is represented by a class instance under the hood, and in this particular case `Predicate<T>` is that class. A "raw" lambda is untyped per se, but it can be implicitly converted to any compatible delegate type.

For instance, `Predicate<FindPerson>` is a compatible delegate type in this example, but so is `Func<FindPerson, bool>`. The same lambda would also be convertible to `Expression<Func<FindPerson, bool>>`, but this is an *entirely* different matter. This is why you can't write `var fn = (int x) => x;` in C#, as 
the type of `fn` cannot be inferred from this expression alone.

As a recap, these are all equivalents:

```
// Compact lambda
lst.Find(a => a.Name.Equals("Alex"))

// Explicitly typed parameter
lst.Find((FindPerson a) => a.Name.Equals("Alex"))

// Explicit delegate type
lst.Find(new Predicate<FindPerson>(a => a.Name.Equals("Alex")))

// Combination of the two above
lst.Find(new Predicate<FindPerson>((FindPerson a) => a.Name.Equals("Alex")))

// Explicit delegate type through casting
lst.Find((Predicate<FindPerson>)(a => a.Name.Equals("Alex")))

// Lambda block
lst.Find(a => { return a.Name.Equals("Alex"); })

// Delegate block
lst.Find((Predicate<FindPerson>)(delegate(FindPerson a) { return a.Name.Equals("Alex"); }))

// ... etc
```

Comment: Thank you very much , your answer me this question resolved

Answer (score 0):

The first example uses what's called a "lambda" expression (introduced in .Net 3.5) which is a simpler, more succinct (and I think) more elegant way to express anonymous delegates. The second code is the older, more verbose way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

They are identical in terms of the `IL` code generated. The first one is a lot nicer to read and write, though - and is generally more common. Delegates are very rarely used nowadays.

Comment: "Delegates are very rarely used nowadays."

What?

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse I am speaking in terms of the keyword `delegate`, rather than the general meaning of a delegate, which anonymous methods are. I have only ever seen delegates used in conjunction with events. Other than that, anonymous methods with lambda syntax have pretty much replaced it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference except for syntax. `Find` method expects `Predicate<T>` as an argument, and it's on you to decide weather you are gonna create it on your own with `new` keyword, or pass a lambda expression and let compiler do that for you.