# How to get return type of overloaded method in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, syntactic-sugar

I have a struct somewhere:

```
struct A {
  ComplicatedType1 f();
  ComplicatedType2 f(int);
};
```

I want to get the return-type of `f()` using compile-time helpers. I'm trying `std::result_of<>`:

```
using Type = std::result_of<decltype(&A::f)()>::type;
```

But the compiler gives me a reasonable error: "reference to overloaded function could not be resolved".

So I go to SO and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2942442/377393) accepted and upvoted answer, which suggest to make a `static_cast<ComplicatedType1 (A::*)()>(&A::f)` - but I don't have a `ComplicatedType1` at this point. I'm stuck in a recursion.

---

How to get `ComplicatedType1` inside my `using` expression with a minimum of code?

Comment: Could this be a job for decltype?

Comment: Can't you use type deduction with the `auto` keyword?

Comment: `std::result_of` expects as its template argument a *type*, but `&A::f` is not a type; neither is `(&A::f)()`. Furthermore, `result_of` is a special pre-C++11 tool, and superseded by `decltype` for most applications: `decltype( f() )`

Comment: @dyp: fixed the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "but I don't have a ComplicatedType1 at this point."?

Comment: The comment of @JoachimPileborg ´s is important. The reasons for manual return type deduction have -  fortunately - been significantly reduced by the awesome `auto`  keyword.

Comment: @decltype_auto: I want to use this type as an argument type - in my own function declaration.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I want to use this type as an argument type - in my own function declaration.

Comment: @abyss.7: but just depending on the return types of the overloads of a known name of a member function of a single known class A?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thats's a job for [decltype + declval](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct ComplicatedType1 {};
struct ComplicatedType2 {};

struct A {
  ComplicatedType1 f();
  ComplicatedType2 f(int);
};

int main()
{
    using Type = decltype(std::declval<A>().f());
    static_assert(std::is_same<Type,ComplicatedType1>::value,"Oops");
}
```

[live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a7be4a877ebaf70)

EDIT: Changed to get return type of f() (instead of f(int)) and to c++11 (instead of c++14) on Coliru