# assigning overloaded function to function pointer as default value

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers, default-parameters

for a function

```
foo( int (*fnptr)(int) );
```

I want to put a default value for the function pointer `int bar(int)`

ie the default value of the pointer is `bar`

`bar` is also overloaded as

```
double bar (double);
bool bar (bool);
```

how can I assign the value??

I tried

```
foo ( int (*fnptr)(int) = bar);
```

but it doesn't work.

**EDIT**   I'm using MS visual studio and getting error code C2440

'default argument': cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'Error_C (__cdecl *)(HMstd::exception)'

My actual function is a member function of class i defined `exception` of namespace `HMstd`

```
virtual Error_C execute_protocol(Error_C(*execute)(exception ex) = HMstd::MErr);
```

And the function is

```
Error_C MErr(Error_C code);
Error_C MErr(char* desc);
Error_C MErr(exception ex);
```

where `Error_C` is another class

This is the definition of the three overloaded function `HMstd::MErr` is

```
Error_C HMstd::MErr(Error_C code)
{
    std::cout << "\n\nError: An Error Of Code " << int(code) << "     Occured....\n\n";
    return SUCCESS;
}

 Error_C HMstd::MErr(char* desc)
{
    if (desc == NULLPTR)
        return E_NULLPTR;
    std::cout << desc;
    return SUCCESS;
}

Error_C HMstd::MErr(exception ex)
{
    bool Nullar = TRUE;
    bool uninit;
    for (int i = 0;i < 200;i++)
        if (ex.description[i] != '\0')
            Nullar = FALSE;
    uninit = (int(ex.code) == -201) && Nullar;
    if (uninit)
    {
        return UNINIT_PARAMETER;
    }
    MErr(ex.code);
    MErr(ex.description);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting ? It looks fine to me.

Comment: I have no problem compiling such code - Could you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Which compiler/version/platform are you using?

Comment: Yup.  `int bar(int); double bar (double); bool bar (bool); void foo( int (*fnptr)(int)=bar); int main() {} ` compiles and runs for me.

Comment: Note that you need to declare a return type for `foo`.

Comment: In particular, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Work as expected [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c210cd6a2646a02).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer was very simple. I had declared the Function

```
Error_C MErr (exception ex);
```

after declaration of class `exception`

so the virtual member function of class `exception` cannot use this particular overload of the function `MErr` i have no way to implement this default parameter.

Answer (score 3):

**QUICK ANSWER:**

Use type-cast

**SHORT CODE:**

```
// ...
int bar (int) {
  cout << "Right\n";
  // bar(true); // just in case you want to invoke bool bar(bool)
  // bar(0.0f);
  return 0;
}
// ...
int foo (int (*ptr) (int) = static_cast<int (*) (int)>(bar)) {
  return ptr(0);
}
// ...
```

**FULL CODE:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int bar (int) {
  cout << "Right\n";
  // bar(true); // just in case you want to invoke bool bar(bool)
  // bar(0.0f);
  return 0;
}

bool bar (bool) {
  return false;
}

double bar (double) {
  return 0;
}

int foo (int (*ptr) (int) = static_cast<int (*) (int)>(bar)) {
  return ptr(0);
}

int main () {
  return foo();
}
```

**EXPLAINATION:**

You have more than one `bar` so I cannot put `= bar` as default parameter. Because of this, you must specify which `bar`. I used type-casting so the compiler can specify one of these `bar`. I seen that you provide only two `bar` (`bool bar(bool)` and `double bar(double)`, but you cannot convert any of these function to `int bar(int)` (if gcc allows it, program possibly works improperly, especially with `double bar(double)`), so you need to call one of these two in the new `int bar(int)`

**NOTE:**

You can also use *unsafe* C-Style type-casting `(int (*)(int)) bar` instead of `static_cast<int (*) (int)>(bar)` but this is C++

If you're using Turbo C++, the code above probably won't work, so you may prefer C-style type-casting, or just switch to GCC.

**SEE ALSO:**

[How do I specify a pointer to an overloaded function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942426/how-do-i-specify-a-pointer-to-an-overloaded-function)

Comment: in c++ better use `static_cast`

Comment: I afraid `static_cast` being "too advance" for such a simple question. Anyway, I will update it.

Comment: well `static_cast` is even more adequate here as it holds us from doing something that may cause UB :)

Comment: There's nothing advanced about learning to prefer c++ styled casts. Using a chisel instead of a sledgehammer is something all novice programmers should learn as soon as possible.

Comment: @StoryTeller That's why I put "quote/end-quote"

Comment: @DMaster  _"you provide only two bar_ `bool bar(bool)` and `double bar(double)`," i said _also overloaded as_ .., that means that apart from `int bar (int)` it is also overloaded as that

Comment: @WARhead Sorry then! I think you still need to add `int bar(int)` to avoid confusion. Also, if you did that but still get an error message, that weird! Which compiler are you using and how do you invoke your compiler (e.g. `g++ main.cpp -o main`)?

Comment: @WARhead I'm not familiar with Win32 APIs, tell me: Is `HMstd::MErr` a static function? What's its type? Is it a macro?

Comment: @DMaster no this is not a Win32 API `HMstd::MErr` is merely a function that displays the error code on the screen for debugging purposes and during run time error loging. `HMstd::MErr` is not a static function. what you see there is its declaration

Comment: @WARhead It is not a standard function neither! I guess you wrote it, you might want to add your `HMstd` class `HMstd::MErr` function to your question

Comment: @DMaster It is a namepace. Along with the class for which the function `execute_protocol` is declared

Comment: Error C2440 occurs during runtime or compiler-time? (I'm not familiar with VS C++ neither)

Comment: @DMaster compile time error[https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C2440)&rd=true](error help)

Comment: @WARhead Could you please add `static` before `HMstd::MErr` declaration and tell me what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

double bar (double) {
    std::cout << "double bar (double) called" << std::endl;
    return 0.0;
}
bool bar (bool) {
    std::cout << "bool bar (bool) called" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

void foo(std::function<int(int)> fn = [](int p) -> int{ return bar(static_cast<double>(p)); }) {
    fn(2);
}

int main() {
    foo();
}
```

Output:

> double bar (double) called

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/W9QOX0rfp5bpiyjD)

you could also replace usage of the `std::function` with pointer to function if you desire by:

```
void foo(int (*fn_ptr)(int) = +[](int p) -> int{ return bar(static_cast<double>(p)); }) {
    fn_ptr(2);
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4ouwOW88KqjhL3Yu)

Comment: i have just started looking at lambda functions. i cant understand the code very much sorry