# How to get a pointer to any overload of an overloaded function whose overloads aren't known?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, c++17

I have a code structure where I grab an overloaded function pointer, check which overload to execute, `static_cast`the pointer to its correct overload and runs it.

The problem is, the caller function, which is responsible for taking a pointer to *any* overload to this function, can't know the list of existing overloads. That being, code such as this :

```
auto ptr = &foobar;
invoke_correct_overload<decltype(ptr)>(ptr);
```

Cannot work, because the first line is ambiguous. Is there a way to specify that the overload doesn't matter in the first line, or that it should be the first overload the compiler finds ?

#### Context

I have a variable number of `std::variant`, and need to feed it to different functions depending on the value they hold. I have figured out a way with a constexpr array to find which overload to execute, and am writing a function that takes a pointer to a function, casts all the variants according to an index in the array, and executing it.

#### Current attempt

```
#define GENERAL_INTERFACE(SPE_FUNC, OPERANDS) do {\
        int valid_comb_index = evaluate_valid_types(valid_args_##SPE_FUNC, OPERANDS)); \
        constexpr [[maybe_unused]] auto foo = SPE_FUNC; \
        invoke_right_overload<valid_args_##SPE_FUNC.size(), \
                              valid_args_##SPE_FUNC[0].size() - 1, \                                   
                              valid_args_##SPE_FUNC, decltype(foo)> \                                                           
                              (valid_comb_index, OPERANDS,foo); \

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t P,
const std::array<std::array<int, 1>, N>& valid_args, typename T>
void invoke_right_overload(int valid_comb_index, 
std::vector<Operand> operands, T& funcptr) {
   if(valid_comb_index == P - 1) {
          auto to_invoke = static_cast<void(*)(decltype(std::get<valid_args[P][0]>(Operand())))>(funcptr);

          std::invoke(to_invoke, std::get<valid_args[P][0]>(operands[0]));
   }

   if constexpr (P - 1 == 0) return;

   invoke_right_overload<N, P - 1,  valid_args, T>(valid_comb_index, 
   operands, funcptr, apply_to);
   }
```

The problem is with the function that *calls* invoke_right_overload. There are multiple "overloads" of invoke_right_overload for 0, 1, 2 or 3 operands, so I can't get the overload using the first valid combination, for there may be none.

*I know this question isn't really well-formed, but cannot find any specific point to make better. I will edit the question as much as you like for more information.*

Comment: A bit more context would be helpful, especially a minimal, complete example.

Comment: Some context was added. Is it enough ?

Comment: That's better, but a complete example would be a lot more helpful. Something that *almost* compiles, but that we can iterate on and get working.

Comment: So you have a variant, and you want to call a different function based on the type stored in that variant? Because there's `std::visit` for that.

Comment: Does [`std::visit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) not do what you want?

Comment: Ehmmm, no: I suppose isn't enough: please a minimal and complete example; I stress the **complete** point

Comment: Each overload has its own address, you know that right?

Comment: I will look into std::visit and then come back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lambda instead of a raw function pointer along with [`std::visit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit):

```
void foo(int) { std::cout << "int\n"; }
void foo(double) { std::cout << "double\n"; }

int main() {
    auto f = [](auto... params) { foo(params...); };

    std::variant<int, double> v = 42;
    std::visit(f, v); // will call foo(int)
    v = 3.14;
    std::visit(f, v); // will call foo(double)
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45385744b38cbd5a)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is the point of your problem but if this instruction

```
auto to_invoke = static_cast<
 void(*)(decltype(std::get<valid_args[P][0]>(Operand())))>(funcptr);
```

is the attempt to change the pointer of a `foobar()` function with a specific signature to a pointer of a function with the same `foobar()` name but a different signature... simply can't work: a pointer to a function is a pointer to a function and you can't simply cast it to a pointer to another function hoping to intercept a function with the same name hoping that the call can work.

Comment: Doesn't your answer go in contradiction with https://stackoverflow.com/a/2942442/7588952 ?

Comment: @Sachiko.Shinozaki - no... I don't think so; with `void (*fpc)(char) = &f;` your saying the compiler: "select the pointer to the specific `f()` function that receive a `char` and return `void`", so the compiler know the right `f()` to choose; the same (If I'm not wrong) with `static_cast<void (*)(char)>(&f)`; but in your case you have selected **before** a specific `f()` pointer and you can't convert to another `f()`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
auto to_invoke = static_cast<void(*)(decltype(std::get<valid_args[P][0]>(Operand())))>(funcptr);
```

you don't want a pointer to a function.  You want to invoke a function on a set of operands, and that doesn't require a pointer to a function.

Next, instead of `T& funcptr` take `T&& to_invoke`.  It isn't a pointer; a pointer does not represent multiple overloads.

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  ->decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

#define OVERLOADS_OF(...) \
  [](auto&&...args) \
  RETURNS(__VA_ARGS__( decltype(args)(args)... )
```

Now if you want to dispatch to overloads of a function `foo` pass `OVERLOADS_OF(foo)` as `to_invoke`.