# In C++ 03, how to refer to the address of an instiantiated template function?

Tags: c++

Assuming that `&` is not overloaded. How to obtain the address of an instantiated template function, such as `std::sort<int*>`? The following won't compile on some compilers:

```
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    &std::sort<int*>;
}
```

ON MSVC v19.21, it reports: https://godbolt.org/z/gpZCdn

```
error C2568: 'identifier': unable to resolve function overload
```

Comment: Is this an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Specifying the template arguments of a standard algorithm is UB IIRC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I specify a pointer to an overloaded function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942426/how-do-i-specify-a-pointer-to-an-overloaded-function)

Comment: @JeJo Thanks, but the question focuses on a more generic situation. The code snippet is just used as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
&std::sort<int*>;
```

`&std::sort<int>` does not work since the type needs to be dereferenceable.

The ambiguity can be resolved by performing an explicit cast.

```
static_cast<void (*)(int*, int*)>(&std::sort<int*>);
```

Comment: no, `std::sort<int>` will indeed not compile but the issue the OP is having is that the overload is ambiguous

Comment: I edited the question so that the ambiguity in the question itself (around `std::sort`) is clarified.

Comment: @xuhdev, interesting. It works with g++ 5.4 at the same site.

Comment: @RSahu I know it works with gcc, but it doesn't seem to be supported by all compilers, even if they fully support C++ 03. clang 3.2 also won't compile this example.

Comment: @xuhdev, did you try the `static_cast`?

Answer (score 3):

- Sort doesn't depend on a type, it depends on an iterator type.
- There are multiple overloads of std::sort, so you need to help the compiler
  choose which one via the function prototype.
- No need to use & to get the address - the name is the address.

Example:

```
void (*func_ptr)(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator) =
     std::sort< std::vector<int>::iterator >;

std::vector<int> values;
for(int i = 99; i > 0; --i) 
  values.push_back(i);

func_ptr(values.begin(), values.end());
```

And if you really want int* as your iterator type

```
void (*func_ptr)(int*, int*) = std::sort<int*>;
```

Comment: std::sort returns void. You are missing void at the start of the function pointer declaration. See the void in my example above. Just keep in mind that the sort function will work only on the iterator type you have specified. Your simplified example will only work on raw C arrays, and not with lists/vectors/maps etc.