# Accumulate absolute values of a vector

Tags: c++, lambda, accumulate

If I like to accumulate the absolute values of a `std::vector`, I can use a lambda to calculate the absolute value and add it to the sum of `std::accumulate` ([live demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8h0liB)).

```
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main (){
    std::vector<int> vec {1,2,3,-4};
    auto abs_val =[](auto val, auto sum){return sum + std::fabs(val);};
    return std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0, abs_val);
}
```

I would like to write

```
    return std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0, std::fabs());
```

but this does not compile, since a function with the two arguments `sum` and `value` is expected.

Is there a more elegant way to write this? Do I need the lambda? Can I get rid of it?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [`transform_reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce) There is an overload (number 3 on that page) that takes a unary operator that could be useful. Requires C++17. Cannot check this myself because my compiler is too old for that.

Comment: Why are you using `fabs()` when your vector is <int>?

Comment: @RHertel That is the answer.  Please post it as such.

Comment: fabs is defined in cmath header file https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges

Comment: @Adrian I like to use this for double and int values. This is why I have used `std::fabs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Before C++17**

You basically want to do two things: Transform the elements and then sum them. For `std::accumulate` you have to tell the algorithm how you want to sum the elements up, but if you want to transform the elements, you need to do something extra.

The line you want to write only tells how to transform the elements (and it doesnt compile, because `accumulate` expects a functor that adds elements not one that transforms them).

TL;DR: No. If you want to transform and add elements, you have to do both. There is no algorithm called `transform_and_accumulate`, so you have to combine something yourself.

**C++17**

The above is true only till C++17, which has [`transform_reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce) and that basically does what you are looking for.

Comment: @RHertel just saw your comment (the link is broken)

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues with the way you would like to pass fabs. The first is trivial, the other one somewhat more involved. The code you showed cannot work, as you are trying to call fabs and pass the result to std::accumulate(a float or double):

```
std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0, std::fabs()); //note the parens ()
```

So, if std::fabs were simply one function and used the correct signature this would work:

```
std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0, std::fabs);
```

Yet, as can be seen [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs), fabs is overloaded on float, double and long double, meaning std::fabs is an overload set, not one single function and as such it's not clear which versions address you would like to pass. That part of the question has an answer here: [How do I specify a pointer to an overloaded function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942426/how-do-i-specify-a-pointer-to-an-overloaded-function)

Furthermore, as stated in the comments and other answer, accumulates last parameter expects a binary operation combining two values, whereas fabs only takes the absolute value of one. The correct algorithm to use is C++17's [transform_reduce](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce):

```
std::transform_reduce(vec.begin(), vec.end(),0,std::plus<>{}, static_cast<double (*)(double)>(std::fabs));
```