# Non-overloaded function yields unresolved overloaded error when used as default argument for concept

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

## Background

As per [[temp.arg.template]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.arg.template#1),

> A template-argument for a template template-parameter shall be the
> name of a class template or an alias template, expressed as
> id-expression.

which means that it is not possible to pass a function template as a default template template argument.

As expected, the following code snippet:

```
template <typename>
void func() {}

template <template <typename> typename Wrapper = decltype(&func)>
struct Foo {};
```

results in the error below (Clang):

```
error: default template argument for a template template parameter must be a class template
template <template <typename> typename Wrapper = decltype(&func)>
```

## Problem

However, when a function template is provided as a default template template argument constrained by concept, this raises a different error:

```
void placeholder() {}

void func(std::invocable auto f) {}

template <typename Fn, typename FnArg>
concept FooConcept = std::is_invocable_v<FnArg>;

template <FooConcept<decltype(&placeholder)> Wrapper = decltype(&func)>
struct Foo {};
```

This, surprisingly, yields an overloaded error:

Clang

```
error: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did you mean to call it?
template <FooConcept<decltype(&placeholder)> Wrapper = decltype(&func)>
```

GCC

```
error: 'decltype' cannot resolve address of overloaded function
   99 | template <FooConcept<decltype(&placeholder)> Wrapper = decltype(&func)>
```

When `decltype(&func)` is replaced with a functor, which is a class template,

```
void placeholder() {}

template <typename Fn, typename FnArg>
concept FooConcept = std::is_invocable_v<FnArg>;

struct Functor {
    auto operator()(std::invocable auto f) -> void {}
};

template <FooConcept<decltype(&placeholder)> Wrapper = Functor>
struct Foo {};
```

This compiles without an error.

## Question

1. Is this derived from the error in **Background** but showing a different message?
2. If not, how come it shows an error related to an overloaded function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is this derived from the error in Background but showing a different message?

No, it's totally unrelated. The background error is trying to pass in a type as a default argument for a parameter expecting a template: it's just the wrong *kind* of argument.

> 2. If not, how come it shows an error related to an overloaded function?

What you're trying to do reduces to:

```cpp
void func(auto f) {}
using T = decltype(&func); // error
```

There is no *one* type of `func` - `func` isn't a function, it's a function template. It can be used to instantiate many different functions which have many different types. There's not enough information here to pick *which* overload that is being selected.

You'd have to manually choose, as in:

```cpp
using T = decltype(static_cast<void(*)(int)>(func)); // ok
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942426/how-do-i-specify-a-pointer-to-an-overloaded-function).

The fact that the parameter that `decltype(&func)` is intended to be a default argument for is constrained by `invocable` doesn't matter - that information doesn't participate in the overload resolution necessary to pick which `func` is the desired one.

---

Providing `Functor` as a default argument works fine because that is already a type, so it just works.