# overload cuda kernel function

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, overloading

I encountered a problem when using the overloaded kernel functions in CUDA.

I can understand CUDA can launch an overloaded function by its arguments.

However, if I would like to use `cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize()` to calculate the block size for maximum occupancy, see [doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OCCUPANCY.html).

```
__global__ void foo_cuda_kernel(int a)
{
  /*implementation 1*/
}

//overloaded kernel function
__global__ void foo_cuda_kernel(int a, int b)
{
  /*implementation 2*/
}

void foo_cuda()
{
  int min_grid_size, grid_size, block_size;
  cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize
  (
    &min_grid_size, &block_size, 
    foo_cuda_kernel, //how does it distinguish overloaded functions?
    0, thread_num
  );
  grid_size = (thread_num + block_size - 1) / block_size;
  
  //I can understand compiler can distinguish the launched function by its arguments
  foo_cuda_kernel<<<grid_size, block_size>>>((int)1);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

How to make it works? How `cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize()` distinguishes overloaded functions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I specify a pointer to an overloaded function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942426/how-do-i-specify-a-pointer-to-an-overloaded-function)

Comment: not sure it works for cuda or not.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, you can cast the function to a pointer to the correct specialization:

```
auto foo_ii = static_cast<void (*)(int, int)>(&foo_cuda_kernel);
auto foo_i = static_cast<void (*)(int)>(&foo_cuda_kernel);
```

You then pass either `foo_i` or `foo_ii` to `cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize`, depending on which version of the function you require.

This will work because the toolchain silently emits host boilerplate functions which wrap the underlying runtime  API calls to run a kernel and enforce kernel argument type checking. The host compiler treats these wrappers like any other host function (because they are), and selects the matching version automagically.