# Error: conversion from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to non-scalar type <functional>

Tags: c++, stl

Interesting thing: If you remove private `quick_sort()` function, program will work fine.

> Stackoverflow tells me to add some details because there are too many
> lines of code. My idea is that private overloaded function somehow
> confuses the compiler. It doesn't know which of `quick_sort()`'s to choose
> or something like this

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<template<class> class T, class V>
class Sorter {
public:
    static void quick_sort(T<V>* seq, std::function<int (V, V)> comp);
    static clock_t sort_time(std::function<void(T<V>*, std::function<int(V, V)>)> sort, T<V>* seq, std::function<int(V, V)> comp);
private:
    // This function is overloaded and private because
    // It works recursively
    static void quick_sort(T<V>* seq, std::function<int (V, V)> comp, int start, int end);
};

template<template<class> class T, class V>
void Sorter<T, V>::quick_sort(T<V>* seq, std::function<int (V, V)> comp) {
    quick_sort(seq, comp, 0, seq->vec.size() - 1);
}

template<template<class> class T, class V>
void Sorter<T, V>::quick_sort(T<V>* seq, std::function<int (V, V)> comp, int start, int end) {
    // ...
}
template<template<class> class T, class V>
clock_t Sorter<T, V>::sort_time(std::function<void (T<V>*, std::function<int (V, V)>)> sort, T<V>* seq, std::function<int (V, V)> comp) {
    // ...
    return clock();
}

int comp(int num1, int num2) {
    // ...
    return 0;
}

template<class T>
class Sequence {
public:
    std::vector<T> vec;
    Sequence(){};
};

int main()
{
    Sequence<int> seq;
    seq.vec = {2, 6, 3, 8};
    
    // Problem is here too
    // std::function<void(Sequence<int>*, std::function<int(int, int)>)> sort = Sorter<Sequence, int>::quick_sort;
    std::cout << "Sort time: " << Sorter<Sequence, int>::sort_time(Sorter<Sequence, int>::quick_sort, &seq, comp);

    return 0;
}
```

**Error**

```
<source>:47:67: error: cannot convert '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'std::function<void(Sequence<int>*, std::function<int(int, int)>)>'
   47 |     std::cout << "Sort time: " << Sorter<Sequence, int>::sort_time(Sorter<Sequence, int>::quick_sort, &seq, comp);
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:46:101: error: conversion from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to non-scalar type 'std::function<void(Sequence<int>*, std::function<int(int, int)>)>' requested
   46 |     std::function<void(Sequence<int>*, std::function<int(int, int)>)> sort = Sorter<Sequence, int>::quick_sort;
      |                                                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~
<source>:47:67: error: cannot convert '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'std::function<void(Sequence<int>*, std::function<int(int, int)>)>'
   47 |     std::cout << "Sort time: " << Sorter<Sequence, int>::sort_time(Sorter<Sequence, int>::quick_sort, &seq, comp);
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:23:88: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'static clock_t Sorter<T, V>::sort_time(std::function<void(T<V>*, std::function<int(V, V)>)>, T<V>*, std::function<int(V, V)>) [with T = Sequence; V = int; clock_t = long int]'
   23 | clock_t Sorter<T, V>::sort_time(std::function<void (T<V>*, std::function<int (V, V)>)> sort, T<V>* seq, std::function<int (V, V)> comp) {
      |                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

Comment: Compiled well after the questions was updated according to the duplicated question. https://godbolt.org/z/cM89vnzxa Since the question was updated, the original error message and title are nonsenses.

Comment: @S.M., I see... So, thats probably because of simplifying. I wasn't even expecting that obvious and simple changes may fix the error :) I will edit question with 'full' version of my code today

Comment: @user4581301, Updated. I have double-checked this [here](https://godbolt.org/z/6E71qhGoW). I've found small complete and reproduces the error, I hope)

Comment: This is a different error from the one you had before, but something we can work with. Voting to reopen.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Kz77fr3jf you can use standart function pointers and it will work

Comment: I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942426/how-do-i-specify-a-pointer-to-an-overloaded-function) 'duplicate' question and I know about standard function pointers but anyway can't make it work with `<functional>`