# Why can't I use std::invoke for std::stoi?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I want to write code like `std::invoke(std::stoi, "a")` but I got some error:

```
No matching function for call to 'invoke'clang(ovl_no_viable_function_in_call)
functional(85, 5): Candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Callable'
```

So I am confused. Could anyone tell me why I can't call `std::stoi` by `std::invoke`?

I think it is about default parameters or overloaded functions.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to call `std::stoi` via `std::invoke` instead of normally?

Comment: In any case, behavior is unspecified if you try to form a pointer or reference to a standard library function (except in a few specific exceptions, not including `std::stoi`) and you are trying to do that here by passing `std::stoi` to `std::invoke`.

Comment: ```stoi``` is overloaded for ```string``` and ```wstring```. Creating function pointers to overloaded functions is tedious. You probably don't need this. ```invoke``` has very specific uses. Why do you think you need it here?

Comment: @Homer512 @user17732522  Because My team try to use template function to catch exception and don't throw them, returning a error_code instead. so that I think I can use `std::invoke` to transfer all the function invoke.

Comment: Well, I don't really get what you are doing but I understand that you did the right thing and built a minimal reproducible example and that's why the use of invoke seems unnecessary. To solve it, you can apply the techniques outlines here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942426/how-do-i-specify-a-pointer-to-an-overloaded-function

Comment: @Homer512 thanks for your help! I think I should use other way to do this, just like macro definition. Have a nice night~

Comment: Personally, I would go with a lambda, like ```std::invoke([](const std::string& s) { return std::stoi(s); }, "a");```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `std::stoi` has multiple overloads.

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::invoke(std::stoi, "a");
}
```

```
$ g++ -o main main.cpp 
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:5:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘invoke(<unresolved overloaded function type>, const char [2])’
    5 |     std::invoke(std::stoi, "a");
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/12/functional:107:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> std::invoke_result_t<_Callable, _Args ...> std::invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)’
  107 |     invoke(_Callable&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
      |     ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12/functional:107:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:5:16: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘_Callable’
    5 |     std::invoke(std::stoi, "a");
```

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Wrap the call in a generic lambda so that the decision about which overload to use is not made until the types of the arguments are known. This is the approach you should use!

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::invoke([]<typename ... T>(T&& ... v) {
        return std::stoi(std::forward<T>(v) ...);
    }, "a");
}
```

2. Alternatively, you can select the appropriate overload directly using `static_cast` and thus pass a unique reference to the function. Unfortunately, default arguments do not work with this approach and it is poorly readable as well.

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::invoke(
        static_cast<int(&)(std::string const&, std::size_t*, int)>(std::stoi),
        "a", nullptr, 10);
}
```

## Detailed explanation

Below you can see a simplified prototype of `invoke`. These four lines are at the beginning of each of the following programs.

```
template <typename Fn, typename ... T>
void invoke(Fn&& fn, T&& ... v){
    fn(static_cast<T&&>(v) ...);
}
```

> Side note: `static_cast<T&&>` is the same as `std::forward<T>`.

We called with `function` as argument.

```
template <typename Fn, typename ... T>
void invoke(Fn&& fn, T&& ... v){ /* ... */ }

void function(int arg) {}

int main() {
    invoke(function, 5);
}
```

Since `function` has no overloads, everything works as expected.

As soon as you add an overload of `function` you get the same error as above.

```
void function(int arg) {}
void function(float arg) {}

int main() {
    invoke(function, 5);
}
```

A template has the same effect as a normal overload.

```
template <typename T>
void function(T arg1) {}

int main() {
    invoke(function, 5);
}
```

```
$ g++ -o main main.cpp 
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:10:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘invoke(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int)’
   10 |     invoke(function, 5);
      |     ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:2:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class Fn, class ... T> void invoke(Fn&&, T&& ...)’
    2 | void invoke(Fn&& fn, T&& ... v){
      |      ^~~~~~
main.cpp:2:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:10:11: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘Fn’
   10 |     invoke(function, 5);
      |     ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If you have no overload but default argument, then the call itself works. But inside `invoke` an error occurs, because the passed reference of the function has no more information about the standard arguments, so that the call fails at this point.

```
void function(int arg1, float arg2 = 0.f) {}

int main() {
    invoke(function, 5);
}
```

```
$ g++ -o main main.cpp 
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void invoke(Fn&&, T&& ...) [with Fn = void (&)(int, float); T = {int}]’:
main.cpp:9:11:   required from here
main.cpp:3:7: error: too few arguments to function
    3 |     fn(static_cast<T&&>(v) ...);
      |     ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

You must be aware that it is not *`function`* that is passed, but a *reference to a function that has an `int` and a `float` as parameters and that returns `void`*. This is all the information the compiler has inside `invoke`.

A generic lambda contains a template, but is itself a unique structure.

```
void function(int arg1, float arg2 = 0.f) {}
void function(double arg) {}

int main() {
    invoke([]<typename ... T>(T&& ... v) {
        function(static_cast<T&&>(v) ...);
    }, 5);
}
```

is just another notation for

```
void function(int arg1, float arg2 = 0.f) {}
void function(double arg) {}

struct compiler_generated_lambda_name {
    template <typename ... T>
    void operator()(T&& ... v) const {
        function(static_cast<T&&>(v) ...);
    }
};

int main() {
    invoke(compiler_generated_lambda_name{}, 5);
}
```

`compiler_generated_lambda_name{}` creates an object of the class `compiler_generated_lambda_name` and this can of course normally be passed to `invoke`. Inside `invoke` the function operator `operator()` of the class is then called with the arguments passed to `invoke`. Thus, the instantiation of the `operator()` template was performed only when the types of the arguments were known.

In our case, of course, we know the type and argument at the time we call `invoke`, so a normal non-generic lambda can be used here.

```
void function(int arg1, float arg2 = 0.f) {}
void function(double arg) {}

int main() {
    invoke([](int v) { function(v); }, 5);
}
```

However, if we have this information, we do not need `invoke` for the call. In reality you use `invoke` only in generic code, so in the explanation I always used the generic variant as wrapper.

```
void function(int arg1, float arg2 = 0.f) {}
void function(double arg) {}

int main() {
    auto function_wrapper =
        []<typename ... T>(T&& ... v) {
            function(static_cast<T&&>(v) ...);
        };

    // the generic wrapper works always
    invoke(function_wrapper, 4);
    invoke(function_wrapper, 4, 2.f);
    invoke(function_wrapper, 4.2);
}
```