# Alternatives to using lambda to inform compiler which function definition is intended

Tags: c++, function, lambda

Say I have two overloaded function definitions:

```cpp
int function_name(std::string);
int function_name(std::string, std::string);
```

I then use one of those functions as a parameter for a struct

```cpp
struct My_struct
{
   std::function<int(std::string)> function_name;
}

...

My_struct function_struct = { function_name };
```

This gives an error because the compiler has no way of knowing which function I intend to give it.

As seen in this post, [How do I specify a pointer to an overloaded function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942426/how-do-i-specify-a-pointer-to-an-overloaded-function?noredirect=1&lq=1), pointed out by @FantasticMrFox below, one solution is to use `static_cast` like so:

```cpp
static_cast<int(*)(std::string)>(function_name);
```

However, an alternative is to use a lambda like so:

```cpp
My_struct function_struct = { [](std::string my_string) { return function_name(my_string); };
```

This also informs the compiler which version I intend to use.

Is there a better way to do this? Or some syntax I'm missing that does this in an easier way?

**Edit:**
After discussion in the comments, I edited this post to read more clearly as a comparison between function pointer and lambda.

Comment: @KamilCuk i decided not to close as dup, i thought it was slightly different because of the conversion to std::function and why this needs the correct function pointer. I think we should re-open this unless there is a closer Duplicate.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I don't think I see why you don't consider it as duplicate. Indeed, it's trying to create a `std::function` instead of passing function to algorithm, but the problem is strictly the same (down to taking a template as an argument).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Taking template as an argument? I am not sure what you mean. Also, this question and answer touches on lambdas v function pointers and can be used to compare them. I think it is different enough to have its own answer.

Comment: While writing I was naive to the linked post. But having read that, I will edit question to be more clearly asking about lambdas vs function pointer casts.

Comment: You've made the minor mistake of taking by value then forgetting to move (should be `function_name(std::move(my_string))`). You can even make a handy macro that perfect forwards, which will usually do what you want: https://godbolt.org/z/78qn9hd91

Comment: @Artyer does this still apply to the lambda case? Where would `std::move` go in this case?

Comment: @cam.b I'm talking about in the lambda, the parameter `std::string my_string` in the lambda is currently copied to initialize the argument of `function_name` when it could be moved from, so your lambda should be `[](std::string my_string) { return function_name(std::move(my_string)); }`

Comment: @Artyer I know this was not included in my original question, but if that is an "out" parameter, I would need a copy, correct? If so I will include a note in OP to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is slightly different to the case here: [How do I specify a pointer to an overloaded function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942426/how-do-i-specify-a-pointer-to-an-overloaded-function)

But it is quite similar, you want to get a std::function, but to achieve this you need to select the right function pointer. You will need to do this by informing the compiler which function to resolve with a static cast:

```
int function_name(std::string);
int function_name(std::string, std::string);

...

std::function<int(std::string)> f = static_cast<int(*)(std::string)>(function_name);
```

By defining the correct function pointer specifically you can create your `std::function`.

[Here is a live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3234dcf791d34cbd_)

**HOWEVER!**

Write for readability first and you might be surprised by performance. For me personally seeing this:

```
My_struct function_struct = { [](std::string my_string) { return function_name(my_string); };
```

Is much clearer than this:

```
My_struct f = static_cast<int(*)(std::string)>(function_name);
```

Because you don't need function pointers. And when [you look at the disassembly of each](https://godbolt.org/z/zj8hfKPcc) you may be surprised to find that the lambda version may actually generate less assembly code because the compiler can do more tricky things with it.