# using ranges to filter side by side vectors while remaining readable

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

So imagine i have 2 vectors (for reasons to do with the framework i am working in):

```
std::vector<bool> valid = {false, true, true, false};
std::vector<int> percentages = {2, 50, 3, 100};
```

These vectors represent a batteries validity and the percentage charge. I want to find the minimum charge of the valid batteries. To do this with ranges, the best i can come up with is:

```
auto min = std::get<1>(
    std::ranges::min(
        std::views::zip(valid, percentages) | 
        std::views::filter([](const auto& vals) {return std::get<0>(vals);}), 
    [](const auto& vals0, const auto& vals1) {
    return std::get<1>(vals0) < std::get<1>(vals1);
}));
```

Now [this works](https://godbolt.org/z/q5P5q3Yq4) but it is nearly impossible to read. So the for loop variety would be something like:

```
int min_percentage = 100;
for (const auto& [is_valid, percentage] : std::views::zip(valid, percentages)) {
    if (is_valid) {
        min_percentage = std::min(min_percentage, percentage);
    }
}
```

Which [works just fine as well](https://godbolt.org/z/q5P5q3Yq4).

The second one is *objectively* better. So the question is, **is there a way to write this with ranges whilst keeping the code readable?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the reason that this is poorly readable:

```cpp
auto min = std::get<1>(
    std::ranges::min(
        std::views::zip(valid, percentages) | 
        std::views::filter([](const auto& vals) {return std::get<0>(vals);}), 
    [](const auto& vals0, const auto& vals1) {
    return std::get<1>(vals0) < std::get<1>(vals1);
}));
```

is that it's the wrong algorithm - you want to find the minimum *percentage* but instead the algorithm you're doing is finding the minimum *pair of (valid, percentage)* by percentage.

Simply restructuring to the correct algorithm (the minimum percentage) is a big improvement:

```cpp
auto min = 
    std::ranges::min(
        std::views::zip(valid, percentages)
        | std::views::filter([](const auto& vals) {return std::get<0>(vals);})
        | std::views::values);
```

And there's a proposal in flight ([P2769](https://wg21.link/p2769)) to let you write that lambda as `std::ranges::get_key` (or `std::ranges::get_element<0>`).

Note also that the predicate you passed into `min` wasn't strictly necessary - the default `<` would already do the right thing, since all of the tuples in that range are now `(true, x)`, so the minimum value there is, by definition, the one with the minimum `x`.

---

This is one of those cases where it's like we have a missing algorithm:

```cpp
ranges::min(
    views::zip(valid, percentages)
    | views::filter_map([](auto&& e) -> optional<int> {
        auto& [valid, perc] = e;
        if (valid) {
            return perc;
        } else {
            return nullopt;
        }
    })
);
```

Where `filter_map` takes a `T -> optional<U>` and yields a range of `U`.

In this case though, you can kind of cheat - the exact same algorithm you wrote with your `for` loop you can accomplish with a `transform`: you're mapping invalid batteries to 100:

```cpp
ranges::min(
    views::zip(valid, percentages)
    | views::transform([](auto&& e) {
        auto& [valid, perc] = e;
        return valid ? perc : 100;
    })
);
```

or, more directly:

```cpp
ranges::min(
    views::zip_transform([](bool valid, int perc){
        return valid ? perc : 100;
    }, valid, percentages)
);
```

This has a different semantic in the case where you have no valid batteries (you get a well-defined `100` instead of UB). Although your loop is still well-defined even in the case where there are no batteries (you get `100`) whereas here the empty case is still UB.

Comment: You can `zip_transform`?

Comment: @T.C. Indeed - although would probably read nicer if I could put the lambda last.

Comment: its annoying that `zip_transform`'s last argument can't be the lambda. Even more so for the equivalent `std::optional` method (i.e. this is applicative application). Kind of destroys readability if you inline a lambda and it's not the last argument.

Comment: also, lacking `views::filter_map` is very inconvenient because it turns into `transform(...) | filter(std::identity{}) | transform([](std::optional o){return *o;})`. You end up resorting to a hack like "mapping invalid batteries to 100"

Comment: The `zip_transform` method seems the best, but it does obfuscate what is happening a little

Answer (score 3):

I think it's pretty readible if you name the lambdas:

```cpp
auto is_valid = [](auto const& zipped) { return std::get<0>(zipped); };

auto min = std::ranges::min(
    std::views::zip(valid, percentages) |
    std::views::filter(is_valid) |
    std::views::values
);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/95T8xsq68

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
namespace rv=std::views;
auto min = std::ranges::min(
    rv::zip(valid, percentages) | 
    rv::filter([](const auto& x)
        {return std::get<0>(x);}) |
    rv::values);
```

Equivalently you can use `rv::elements<1>` instead of `rv::values`.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, we could just pass `std::get<0>` as the filter function.

Unfortunately, the compiler fails to deduce the overload, so we have to help it out with a lambda. Since this is a common issue ([How do I specify a pointer to an overloaded function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942426/how-do-i-specify-a-pointer-to-an-overloaded-function)), having a helper macro for it in your project might be reasonable:

```cpp
#define AS_LAMBDA(...) [&](auto&&... args)                          \
    -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...)) \
{                                                                   \
    return __VA_ARGS__(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);      \
}
```

This makes the code look as follows:

```cpp
auto min = std::ranges::min(
   std::views::zip(valid, percentages) |
   std::views::filter(AS_LAMBDA(std::get<0>)) |
   std::views::elements<1>
);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Gaa1ErdGG