# How to force a call to a const qualified function overload?

Tags: c++, constants, overloading

I'm trying to call `const` function inside a class, but a non-`const` function with the same name exists.

Note: I can't just change names.

```
class MyQuestion
{
 void fun()
 {
   cout<<"a"; 
 }

 void fun()const
 { 
   cout<<"b"; 
 }

 void call()
 {
   fun();//<how to call fun() const?
 }
};
```

Comment: It will call one or the other automatically depending on the const-ness of the `*this` pointer

Comment: Relevant answer to a not-quite-duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5326238/10077

Comment: That you need to call the const version of the function just seems so wrong. It means that while your const and non-const member functions happen to have the same name, they are in fact doing fundamentally different things.

Answer (score 25):

#### Option #1:

Call that function through a pointer to a `const` qualified type:

```
void call()
{
    static_cast<const MyQuestion*>(this)->fun();
    //          ~~~~^
}
```

[c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11):

```
void call()
{
    const auto* that = this;
    //~~^
    that->fun();
}
```

[c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17):

```
void call()
{
    std::as_const(*this).fun();
    //   ~~~~~~~^
}
```

#### Option #2:

Make the calling function a `const`-qualified one:

```
void call() const
//          ~~~~^
{
    fun();
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/386416b70a8f7f6e)

Comment: I don't really like the verbosity of the static cast (to explicitly mention the class name). You can avoid that by using a local variable with type `const auto*`.

Comment: Why would a static_cast be appropriate for this, and not a const_cast?

Comment: @Thebluefish `const_cast` usually indicates casting away the *constness* (I'm doing the opposite here), I'm not fond of using it for regular implicit conversions, `const_cast` does its cast unconditionally

Comment: I would use an `implicit_cast` instead of a `static_cast` there (or use a local as @leemes proposes). Even if I have to write it for myself, or import it from boost...

Comment: Rather than use the case I prefer to use a const reference internally. `MyQuestion const& self = *this; self.fun()`

Answer (score 18):

You have to call the function on a *const pointer*. For this, I recommend to create a local pointer variable:

```
const auto *c = this;
c->fun();   // calls fun() const

fun();      // calls fun()
```

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/2zBgzZ)**</kbd>

---

If you need that often, and/or if you don't want to use a local variable, you could also introduce a private helper function which returns a const this pointer:

```
const MyQuestion *const_this() const {
    return this;
}
```

and then call `fun` like this:

```
const_this()->fun();   // calls fun() const

fun();                 // calls fun()
```

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/bdcuHZ)**</kbd>

---

Yet another option is to write a `make_const` function which performs a cast to a const pointer without the need to mention the class name (it's basically a `static_cast` to a const pointer of a deduced type):

```
template <typename T>
const T* make_const(T *ptr) {
    return ptr;
}
```

and then call `fun` like this:

```
make_const(this)->fun();    // calls fun() const

fun();                      // calls fun()
```

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/mhQODV)**</kbd>

---

For the sake of argument (**I don't recommend the following**), combining with the suggestion above, you could also introduce a global macro which expands to `make_const(this)`:

```
#define  const_this  make_const(this)
```

and then call `fun` like this:

```
const_this->fun();   // calls fun() const

fun();               // calls fun()
```

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/TQ3KIb)**</kbd>

Comment: The lambda requires C++14 or an explicit return type. C++11 can only deduce it for lambdas which contain nothing but a single `return` statement.

Comment: @Angew Oh, didn't know that, as g++ allows other statements and I always used lambdas this way... But good to know, thanks :) -- Updated the macro to expand to a function call instead.

Comment: @angew The "only a single line with a return statement" restriction lasted for almost zero time in every major compiler.  C++14 with the restriction removed was on its way, and it was just that easy...

Comment: I call `make_const` `as_const` in my codebase.  And add a `T&` and `T const&` overload.

Comment: @Yakk It seems that with C++17 there is said `as_const()` function in `std::`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const So one does not have to add yet another function to the ever growing list of global utility functions per project.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add another possible solution to the excelent ones already posted.

You can help the compiler to choose the *correct* overload using a function pointer with the expected signature:

```
// Pointer to the version of fun with const
void (MyQuestion::*f)()const = &MyQuestion::fun;
(this->*f)(); // This would call the const fun
```

See the demo [here](http://ideone.com/71vpGZ), or the full code below:

```
struct MyQuestion
{
    void fun()
    {
        std::cout<<"a"; 
    }

    void fun()const
    { 
        std::cout<<"b"; 
    }

    void call()
    {
        void (MyQuestion::*f)()const = &MyQuestion::fun;
        (this->*f)();
    }
};
```

Why does this work?

Well, the type of the `f` pointer is `void (MyQuestion::*)()const` which is the same of `MyQuestion::foo()const` but not the same of `MyQuestion::foo()`, so when you take te address of the function `&MyQuestion::fun` the pointer `f` could only point to the const version.

Answer (score 3):

how about overloading call() itself. Following implementation does the job. I m guessing that it is what you want to implement.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    void fun() { cout << "non" << endl; }
    void fun() const { cout << "const" << endl; }

    void call() { fun(); }
    void call() const { fun(); }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.call();

    const A b;
    b.call();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This may not work -- `call()` may have very good reasons *not* to be const!

Comment: the const call() will only be called only when the object being created is a const which will definitely invoke the const fun()

Comment: How do you know that `call()` and `fun()` are members of the same class?  We could have a scenario where `A::call()` needs to be non-const because it mutates the A object its working on, but needs to get something from a B referenced by the A object using `B::fun() const` where the non-const `B::fun()` does something unwanted to the B object.