# How to avoid operator's or method's code duplication for const and non-const objects?

Tags: c++, operators, duplication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove code duplication between similar const and non-const member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-funct)

My task is to implement c++ vector analogue. I've coded operator[] for 2 cases.

```
T myvector::operator[](size_t index) const {//case 1, for indexing const vector
    return this->a[index];   
} 
T & myvector::operator[](size_t index) {//case 2, for indexing non-const vector and assigning values to its elements
    return this->a[index];
}
```

As you can see, the code is completely equal. It's not a problem for this example (only one codeline), but what should I do if I need to implement some operator or method for both const and non-const case and return const or reference value, respectively? Just copy-paste all the code everytime I make changes in it?

Comment: Why are you returning by value in the const version. You could return a const reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the few good uses of const_cast here.  Write your non const function as normal, then write your const function like so:

```
const T & myvector::operator[](size_t index) const {
    myvector<T> * non_const = const_cast<myvector<T> *>(this);
    return (*non_const)[index];
}
```

Comment: This effectively defeats the `const`. This is as bad a use as any.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Of course it defeats the const.  That's it's purpose.

Comment: Post edit: In order to copy the answer to the question this is getting duped to, you need to cast *to* `const` in the non-const method. This way is illegal.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: No, it's not illegal.

Comment: @Ben: You are creating and potentially using a non-`const` path to a `const` object. That's illegal even if it compiles.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - no, it's not illegal. It's undefined behavior to modify a const object, it's fine to use a non-const pointer or reference to read it. If the non-const `operator[]` modifies the object, then you're in trouble, but here it doesn't.

Comment: @Steve: ah, I was thinking there was an `operator*` call in there too. Either way, it's cleaner to implement a non-const function which adds const than to rely on the non-const being a valid const implementation.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: true. There's a risk of doing something unsafe whichever you do, though - if const calls non-const then you have to manually ensure the non-const version doesn't modify. If non-const calls const you have to verify that the thing it returns can validly be modified if the object is non-const (for example if T is char, the compiler would let the const version return part of a string literal). Contradicting the answer I gave on the dupe question in 2008, nowadays I'd prefer to write a shared template function, so that the compiler can const-check everything for me.