# Avoid literally duplicating code for const and non-const with auto keyword?

Tags: c++, c++14

Okay, I did some research and apparently there are a lot of duplicate questions on SO on this topic, to name a few:

- [Elegant solution to duplicate, const and non-const, getters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856542/elegant-solution-to-duplicate-const-and-non-const-getters)
- [How to avoid operator's or method's code duplication for const and non-const objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735287/how-to-avoid-operators-or-methods-code-duplication-for-const-and-non-const-obj)
- [How do I remove code duplication between similar const and non-const member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func)

etc.  But I cannot help but raise this again, because

1. With [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) `auto`-typed return value, I am literally duplicating the function body with the only difference being the `const` function qualifier.
2. It is possible that `const` version and non-`const` version may return types that are totally incompatible from each other.  In such cases, neither Scott Meyers's `const_cast` idiom, nor the "private `const` function returning non-`const`" technique would work.

As an example:

```
struct A {
    std::vector<int> examples;
    auto get() { return examples.begin(); }
    auto get() const { return examples.begin(); }
};  // Do I really have to duplicate?
    // My real-world code is much longer
    // and there are a lot of such get()'s
```

In this particular case, `auto get()` returns an `iterator` while `auto get() const` returns a `const_iterator`, and the two cannot be converted into each other (I know `erase(it,it)` trick does the conversion in this case but that's not the point).  The `const_cast` hence does not work; even if it works, that requires the programmer to manually deduce `auto` type, totally defeating the purpose of using `auto`.

So is there really no way except with macros?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove code duplication between similar const and non-const member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func) I don't see how this is not answered in the other question.

Comment: @Drise in this case the technique doesn't seem to apply because `::const_iterator != const ::iterator`

Comment: Meyer's method clearly doesn't work for member functions returning different types in `const` and non-`const` versions, but I'd say that's a rather uncommon case, out of iterators (although I may be wrong). Not sure if it's possible to work out a general solution but maybe you could have a function to [convert `const_iterator` to `iterator`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/765148) (say `unconst_iterator`) and have a pattern like `auto get() { return unconst_iterator(example, static_cast<const A &>(*this).get()); }`.

Comment: @jdehesa fair enough.  In my case it's not `iterator` but something very close (two similar classes, one with `const` members).  I could indeed write a type conversion between the two.  Thanks for the advice, yet still hopefully awaiting more elegant answers.

Comment: Do you have access to C++ 17 @Pigpag ?

Comment: It seems your only concrete objection to the Meyer's style solution
is that the two functions "may return types that are totally incompatible from each other."
In such a case, where's the duplication of the function body?

Comment: @Carl unfortunately only [tag:C++14]

Comment: @MikeKinghan just read my example above.  with `auto` return type, this is totally possible.

Comment: [P0847](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0847r0.html) hopes to solve this problem

Comment: Also possibly related (but not a duplicate):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150192/how-to-avoid-code-duplication-implementing-const-and-non-const-iterators

Comment: I think this issue is generally overdramatized. Unless you have fairly complex getter methods, just copy pasting the code is usually more readable easier to analyze and easier to maintain than jumping to all kinds of hoops and writing boilerplate  code to prevent code duplication. The resulting code might have fewer redundancies, but it tends to be longer and more complex overall.

Comment: @MikeMB Yes, I agree. Copying a bit of code is not that bad in most cases. Nevertheless I just find that the current standard might have missed something to fully take advantage of auto type inferrence. A lot of things are being added, so eventually people may realize that "now that I have A, I really don't need B anymore - let's make the standard evolve", which causes a chain reaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after a bit of tinkering I came up with the following two solutions that allow you to keep the auto return type and only implement the getter once. It uses the opposite cast of what Meyer's does.

### C++ 11/14

This version simply returns both versions in the implemented function, either with `cbegin()` or if you don't have that for your type this should work as a replacement for `cbegin()`: `return static_cast<const A&>(*this).examples.begin();` Basically cast to constant and use the normal `begin()` function to obtain the constant one.

```
// Return both, and grab the required one
struct A
{
private:
    // This function does the actual getter work, hiding the template details
    // from the public interface, and allowing the use of auto as a return type
    auto get_do_work()
    {
        // Your getter logic etc.
        // ...
        // ...

        // Return both versions, but have the other functions extract the required one
        return std::make_pair(examples.begin(), examples.cbegin());
    }

public:
    std::vector<int> examples{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    // You'll get a regular iterator from the .first
    auto get()
    {
        return get_do_work().first;
    }

    // This will get a const iterator
    auto get() const
    {
        // Force using the non-const to get a const version here
        // Basically the inverse of Meyer's casting. Then just get
        // the const version of the type and return it
        return const_cast<A&>(*this).get_do_work().second;
    }

};
```

### C++ 17 - Alternative with if constexpr

This one should be better since it only returns one value and it is known at compile time which value is obtained, so `auto` will know what to do. Otherwise the `get()` functions work mostly the same.

```
// With if constexpr
struct A
{
private:
    // This function does the actual getter work, hiding the template details
    // from the public interface, and allowing the use of auto as a return type
    template<bool asConst>
    auto get_do_work()
    {
        // Your getter logic etc.
        // ...
        // ...

        if constexpr (asConst)
        {
            return examples.cbegin();

            // Alternatively
            // return static_cast<const A&>(*this).examples.begin();
        }
        else
        {
            return examples.begin();
        }
    }

public:
    std::vector<int> examples{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    // Nothing special here, you'll get a regular iterator
    auto get()
    {
        return get_do_work<false>();
    }

    // This will get a const iterator
    auto get() const
    {
        // Force using the non-const to get a const version here
        // Basically the inverse of Meyer's casting, except you get a
        // const_iterator as a result, so no logical difference to users
        return const_cast<A&>(*this).get_do_work<true>();
    }
};
```

This may or may not work for your custom types, but it worked for me, and it solves the need for code duplication, although it uses a helper function. But in turn the actual getters become one-liners, so that should be reasonable.

The following main function was used to test both solutions, and worked as expected:

```
int main()
{    
    const A a;
    *a.get() += 1; // This is an error since it returns const_iterator

    A b;
    *b.get() += 1; // This works fine

    std::cout << *a.get() << "\n";
    std::cout << *b.get() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now you need 3 methods for every getter instead of 2. It didn't really get any simpler…

Comment: But you don't duplicate the function body, keeping the implementations consistent. And changing it in one place doesn't mean you have to change the other, as was asked in the question. Also avoids macros as was requested.

Comment: Upvoted.  I think this is a very fair solution :)  Let me wait and see if there are better ones to come

Comment: It should work in principle, although leaves the door open to UB without warning if `get_do_work` modifies the state of the object. I wouldn't even be able to tell for sure whether calling (non-`const`) `.begin()` on a `const_cast`-ed `vector` is guaranteed to be safe.

Comment: Accepted.  I'd like to point out a comment @jonathan-wakely had posted.  It does seem that an existing proposal [P0847](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0847r0.html) targets the exact case I am asking, so I assume there exists no elegant solution within the current standard.

Comment: @Carl: I'm not saying it doesn't answer the question, but I sometimes have to wonder if "solutions" such as this don't result in much bigger maintenance problems than minor code duplication.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct A {
    std::vector<int> examples;

private:
    template <typename ThisType>
    static auto
    get_tmpl(ThisType& t) { return t.examples.begin(); }

public:
    auto get()       { return get_tmpl(*this); }
    auto get() const { return get_tmpl(*this); }
};
```

How about the above? Yes, you still need to declare both methods, but the logic can be contained in a single static template method. By adding a template parameter for return type this will work even for pre-C++11 code.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hypothetical solution, that I am thinking about applying every where once we will have concepts: *using friend free function in place of member function*.

```
//Forwarding ref concept
template<class T,class U>
concept FRef = std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>,std::decay_t<U>>;

struct A{
  std::vector<int> examples;

  friend decltype(auto) get(FRef{T,A}&& aA){
    return std::forward<T>(aA).examples.begin();
      //the std::forward is actualy not necessary here 
      //because there are no overload value reference overload of begin.
    }
  };
```