# C++ 11x check: how to implement const-variants?

Tags: c++, c++11

Pre C++ 11, I often needed to implement two very-alike variants of a method to deal with const and non-const usage scenarios of the class/struct:

```
struct my_struct_t{
     ....
     float_t& at( uint32_t row, uint32_t col)
     {
         return *(((float_t*)((uint8_t*)numbers+row*row_stride)) + col);
     }

     float_t const& at( uint32_t row, uint32_t col) const
     {
         return *(((float_t*)((uint8_t*)numbers+row*row_stride)) + col);
     }

};
```

Has this changed in C++ 11?

Comment: If both variants are doing exactly same then you can keep the `const` variant and get away with the other one.

Comment: I don't believe your first one would work . return a reference to a non const temporary value.

Comment: @Mike Yes, the returns are flawed, I'm fixing them now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**.
It is evident in the Standard Library (it still uses explicit `const` methods).

Comment: I didn't check STL's implementation because, well, there are several STL implementations. And most of them are tweaked to support pre-C++ 11 compilers, so, they don't necessarily offer a definitive answer.

Comment: @dsign But Mark is right nevertheless, because the C++11 Standard does define the interface for the standard library, and that still provides for const/non-const versions of certain getter-type functions, e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at

Comment: @dsign Yes. They have several implementations. But the constraints and behavior requirements must be met by every correct implementations. Now that doesn't leave much room for difference.

Comment: That settles it then. I just wanted a quick check to see if I was missing something, and I got it! Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2):

This had not changed in C++11, but it has changed in C++17:

```
T const & f() const {
    return something_complicated();
}
T & f() {
    return const_cast<T &>(std::add_const(*this).f());
}
```

See [How do I remove code duplication between similar const and non-const member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func)

**Edit**

I have changed my position a few times since making this post. The text above reflects my current thinking. My previous position was to prefer `const_cast` for both casts, and my original position was `static_cast` then `const_cast`. `const_cast` is safer because the only thing it can do is add / remove `const` and `volatile` qualifiers. `static_cast` can accidentally cast in other ways. My original thinking was to prefer `static_cast` to add `const` as it separates the most likely 'safe' operation of adding `const` from the possibly dangerous operation of removing `const`. The version in the code above has the safe operation spelled out by `std::as_const`, which can do only what I want, leaving the potentially unsafe `const_cast` as the only thing you need to ensure you have done correctly.

Comment: Did you mean `self.f()`?

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe there is a need to get rid of "not implementing 2 variants".

1. If both variants are doing different stuff, then you must have to
   keep them
2. If both variants are doing the same stuff, then remove the
   non-const version and maintain only the `const` version

By the way, there are 3rd and 4th variants if one ever needs:

```
float_t& at( uint32_t row, uint32_t col) volatile;
float_t& at( uint32_t row, uint32_t col) const volatile;
```

[Note: Irrelevant but in C++11 all the variants can be added with `noexcept` keyword for exception related info:

```
float_t& at( uint32_t row, uint32_t col) noexcept;
```

]

Comment: The point is that both versions _do_ the same, but they return something different, typically a const-reference vs. a non-const reference, either to `*this` or to an internal member. A typical example is `operator[]` of containers: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at

Comment: @jogojapan, if methods are returning something different then they are not doing the same :). Returning a non-const reference is modifiable externally but a `const` reference is not.

Comment: @jogojapan put it clear. Maybe I'm missing something, but without the non-const version assignments wouldn't work:   'distances->at( i, j ) = d;'

Comment: @iammilind True. But the way I understand the question it's about instances of two versions of a function that return something different but perform the same operation otherwise, and how to avoid code-duplication then. The main answer (even in C++98) in my opinion is that all non-trivial operations should be performed in a separate (possibly private, non-const) function, and the two versions should only be implemented for a getter, or something similarly trivial.

Comment: (Explaining my downvote.) dsign and jogojapan are right: having const and non-const flavors of otherwise identical accessors is a really common antipattern in C++. Word games may obscure the issue, but they don't make it go away.

Comment: @Quuxplusone, the question is not about the whether const and non-const version are same or not. But, whether they both are still required or not and what's there future in C++11. It still required as it's evident in Standard library.

Comment: @iammilind Correct; I didn't downvote Mark Garcia's answer, which said very succinctly that the antipattern is still present in C++11. I downvoted your answer because you *didn't* say that, but you *did* say you "don't believe there is a need to get rid of" the antipattern, and then pointed out that a conscientious programmer has to write not two but *four* versions— as if this were a good thing!— and *then* threw in an irrelevancy about `noexcept` (which doesn't contribute to the antipattern's combinatorial explosion; it's just another miscellaneous function-related keyword, like `virtual`).