# Inside function, call its overloaded version

Tags: c++, class, overloading

I'm wondering about one thing. I've got class which has 1 overloaded member function:

```
class A{
    public:
    class const_iterator{};
    class iterator : public const_iterator{};
    iterator find(const K &key);
    const_iterator find(const K &key) const;
};
```

Ad. iterator is inheriting from const_iterator, but it isn't adding anything.

What I want to do is, inside normal find call const find. Something like this:

```
typename A::iterator A::find(const K &key){
     const_iterator it(find(key));
     return (*(iterator*)&it);
}
```

I don't need different implementation of non-const find ATM. Is it possible to do something like this? Because now I'm getting into infinite loop, adding "A::" before find isn't changing anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there’s no clean solution for this, unfortunately.

You *can* call the overloaded `find` by simply casting `this` to `A const*` – but the result will be of the wrong type (`const_iterator` rather than `iterator`) and there may not be a conversion between these in the general case (your `(*(iterator*)&it)` won’t work in your case).

But of course, in your special case, since you defined the two classes, you can *define* such a conversion by adding an appropriate constructor to `iterator`:

```
class iterator : public const_iterator {
    iterator(const_iterator const& other) { 
        // Construct …
    }
};
```

Then you can re-write your non-`const` `find` implementation as follows:

```
A::iterator A::find(const int &key){
    const_iterator it(const_cast<A const*>(this)->find(key));
    return static_cast<iterator>(it);
}
```

Incidentally, note the absence of `typename` in the return type. Since `A::iterator` isn’t a dependent name, you don’t need (and, at least in C++03, are not allowed to) use `typename` here.

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked, i need typename because there are templates and so on, also it works with that simple downcasting the pointer, I didn't have to define conversion(maybe because this inhering is mostly only name change and it isn't implementing anything new)

Comment: @MichałDębski No, you *do* need to define the conversion. There is no automatic downcast from base class to derived class. Your pointer cast is forbidden and yields undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

```
const_cast<const A*>(this)->find(key);
```

Comment: @Aardvark - good point. I changed `static_cast` to `const_cast`. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't we use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` or a regular cast? Why does `const_cast<>` have to be used?

Comment: @David Because we change the `const`-ness of the object, nothing more. Furthermore, `dynamic_cast` would be totally wrong here since it only applies to casting within an inheritance hierarchy (and even then only when we’re not sure whether the cast will succeed, and handle the resulting null value accordingly), which isn’t the case here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks. I'm kind of confused with those `---_cast<>` functions.

Comment: `const_cast` changes only the const-ness of the argument. That's the narrowest conversion that gets to the right type. `static_cast` also works, but it can do more than just changing const-ness, so shouldn't be used here. The risk is that a more powerful cast can change other aspects of the type; in a simple case like this one it's not likely, but in more complicated situations a more powerful cast could mask a coding error. In general, use the least-powerful cast that does what's needed.