# Call nonconst member version from const

Tags: c++, constants, overloading, function-qualifier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove code duplication between similar const and non-const member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func)

i have two members

```
A &B::GetA (int i)
{
    return *(m_C[m_AtoC[i]]);
}

const A &B::GetA (int i) const
{
    return *(m_C[m_AtoC[i]]);
}
```

for now i just duplicate code, but may be there exists nice way to do it. I certanly dont want to deal with type cast from const to non-const.

EDIT: So i want to call one member frm another to avoid code duplication.

Comment: What do you want the non-const version for?

Comment: @Beta to be able to modify the member.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `&`.

Comment: A small `#define` would do the trick, but I guess you don't want to use it either ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Note the correction; sorry for getting it the wrong way round initially.]*

This is an appropriate situation for using a `const_cast`, and it allows you to deduplicate code by forwarding the call from the non-const function to the corresponding const function:

```
A & B::GetA(int index) 
{
    return const_cast<A &>(static_cast<B const *>(this)->GetA(index));
}
```

It's important to note that this should only be done in one direction: You can implement the `non-const` method in terms of the constant one, but not the other way round: The constant call to `GetA()` gets a constant reference to the object in question, but since we have additional information that it's *actually* OK to mutate the object, we can safely cast away the constness from the result.

There's even a chapter on precisely this technique in Scott Meyer's *Effective C++*.

Comment: please notice, that the OP explicitly writes "I certanly dont want to deal with type cast from const to non-const."

Comment: @AndyProwl: So what. A const-cast *is* the appropriate solution for this problem.

Comment: I agree (and I am not the one who downvoted it). but since he says that, it would be appropriate to mention explicitly why it is ok

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't think it is.

Comment: @KerrekSB Except that your cast is ill-defined when executed on an instance of `B const`. Do it the other way round, `const`-cast in the non-`const` version.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Yeah, you're right -- I fell into the very trap I was trying to caution against! :-S

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't think it's ill-defined, as the non-const `GetA()` doesn't do any modifications in itself, and the reference will be cast back to `const&` before being passed out of the function. Calling a non-const function on a const object is not UB, only modifying a const object is.

Comment: @Konrad const-casting (i.e. playing around with the *types*) is not UB.

Comment: I don't get this: with this latest solution, aren't you casting away the `const`-ness of the reference returned by the `const` version of `GetA()`? isn't that UB?

Comment: @AndyProwl: No. Only *modifying a constant* object is UB. We're not doing that.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Konrad was right, I had it the wrong way round initially. I hope he agrees now :-)

Comment: @AndyProwl: It's only UB if the referenced `A` object is actually `const` in its original declaration (in which case there's no valid code that will return an `A&`).

Comment: @KerrekSB: ok but you're returning to the client a modifiable reference, so it's likely the client will do that

Comment: @AndyProwl: The object in question *is not constant*.

Comment: @KerrekSB: ok, i got it. but then i fail to see the problem with the original version

Comment: I looked at the revision history. The original was fine as long as GetA is not mutating by itself (and if it does *gasp* whyyyy). No mutation is ever performed. Only types are harmed, never objects. The function still returned a non-modifiable reference.

Comment: The solution seems to have much *more* code that the original. Is that really an advantage? :-)

Comment: @BoPersson Hello and welcome to C++.

Comment: @BoPersson Yes, it is, because if you ever need to change the actual getter code, you'll (sooner or later) forget to change it the same in both places.

Comment: @BoPersson: Imagine if the const version of the function were really long and complex. `strchr`, I'm looking at you :-)

Comment: I am still curious why was the original version wrong. i think comments by @R.MartinhoFernandes are spot on

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I think the distinction comes from your parenthetical: The original version had less locally visible safety. With the current version, you *know* that you're not doing anything wrong; with the original version, you had to know the body of the non-constant function. (But indeed, for the OP's situation the two versions work the same.)

Comment: @KerrekSB wasn't the exercise about the two having *the same* body? If they don't the question is moot.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Hm, OK, fair enough, but the current version leaves no room for error. Its correctness can be seen locally, without checking the implementation of the other function... it just "feels" better :-S

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
class B {
public:
    A& GetA (int index) { return GetA_impl(index); }
    const A& GetA (int index) const { return GetA_impl(index); }
private:
    A& GetA_impl (int index) const { return *(m_C[m_AtoC[i]]); }
};
```

I'm not sure it's really worth the effort in this case, but this can be useful if the potentially duplicated code gets more complicated.

Comment: I assume, if `m_C` is a member, that you're discarding a const qualifier in your private method ...

Comment: @Useless: Depends on the type of `m_C`.  But if it's something typical like a `std::vector<A*>`, this code does not discard a qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid const_cast with a little template metaprogramming.

```
// This meta function returns a const U if T is const, otherwise returns just U.
template <typename T, typename U>
make_same_const<T, U>
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<
            std::is_const<T>::value,
            typename std::add_const<U>::type,
            U
        >::type type;
};


// Generic version of a function. Constness of return type depends on
// constness of T.
// This is a static member template of B.
template <typename T>
make_same_const<T, A>::type& B::GetA(T& obj, int i)
{
    return *(obj.m_C[obj.m_AtoC[i]]);
}

A&       B::GetA(int i)       { return B::GetA(*this, i); }
A const& B::GetA(int i) const { return B::GetA(*this, i); }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
const A &B::GetA (int index) const
{
    return *(const_cast<B*>(this)->GetA(index));
}
```

Comment: not that I don't like it, but the OP writes "I certanly dont want to deal with type cast from const to non-const."

Comment: @AndyProwl I understood this to mean "on the call site"

Comment: how is this different from the original ? Did you mean to post something similar to Kerrek SB's answer ?

Comment: @Angew: hmm, ok maybe it is up to some interpretation

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: this *is* the original answer (notice that this is the first answer that was posted)

Comment: @AndyProwl "Original" as in the code in the question above. Note that this answer casts away constness only to add it back in the return type. The cast is completely pointless here.

Comment: The cast is not pointless. It's what makes it compilable.

Comment: @melpomene the cast is not pointless (try compiling it without it)

Comment: @SanderDeDycker the cast is not pointless, but I did mean to call `GetA` instead, yes. :D

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes The cast was pointless in the original version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

IMO this isn't enough code (or complexity) to be worth de-duplicating.

As you can see in both the `const_cast`-based solutions, the cast expression is actually *longer* than the original code.

If you have a longer or more complex expression you're really worried about, though, please show it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the bodies of `GetA()` and `GetA() const` are identical (which means `GetA()` doesn't modify `*this`), you can safely use one `const_cast` to implement the const version using the non-const one:

```
const A& B::GetA() const {
  return const_cast<B*>(this)->GetA();
}
```

The non-const `GetA()` doesn't modify the object, so calling it on a `const B` object is not undefined. The non-const reference returned by non-const `GetA()` is converted to a `const&` before being returned out of `GetA() const`, so there's no danger of undefined behaviour there either.

Comment: Would the downvoter explain themselves?

Comment: Your answer adds nothing new to the other answers that also ignore the "I certanly dont want to deal with type cast from const to non-const" bit.

Comment: @melpomene It's currently the only answer using `const_cast` in the `const` version (where you don't have to use two) and delegating to the other `GetA()`, not re-implementing. I understood OP's comment to refer to casting constness on the *call site.* But point accepted.