# Compiler can't "convert" between Vector_const_iterator and Vector_iterator, even though methods for both are available

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, stdvector, const-iterator, reverse-iterator

I'm trying to create a small wrapper class around a std::vector to represent the coefficients of a polynomial. The caller needs to be able to iterate through the coefficients, but I don't want to expose the underlying implementation.

Using the pattern described [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/264728/allow-iteration-of-an-internal-vector-without-leaking-the-implementation), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446058/removing-code-duplication-from-const-and-non-const-methods-that-return-iterators), and elsewhere, I've tried to pass along the iterators as below:

```
typedef std::vector<unsigned char> charVec;

class gf255_poly
{
    public:

        // Constructors and Polynomial-y Functions

        // ...

        // Iterators to go from high to low degree

        charVec::const_reverse_iterator h2l_begin() const { return p.rbegin(); };
        charVec::const_reverse_iterator h2l_end()   const { return p.rend(); };
        charVec::reverse_iterator       h2l_begin() { return p.rbegin(); };
        charVec::reverse_iterator       h2l_end()   { return p.rend(); };

        // Iterators to go from low to high degree

        charVec::const_iterator l2h_begin() const { return p.begin(); };
        charVec::const_iterator l2h_end()   const { return p.end(); };
        charVec::iterator       l2h_begin() { return p.begin(); };
        charVec::iterator       l2h_end()   { return p.end(); };

    protected:
        std::vector<unsigned char> p;
};
```

These gf255_poly objects then get used in methods such as this one:

```
// Performs polynomial evaluation in GF(2^8)
unsigned char gf255_poly_eval(const gf255_poly &poly, unsigned char x) const
{
    unsigned char fx = poly.coefHigh(); // Initialize with coef of highest degree term

    // Use Horner's method with consecutively factored terms:
    // x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x + 4 -> (((1x + 2)x + 3)x + 4)

    charVec::reverse_iterator next_coef;

    for (next_coef = poly.h2l_begin(); next_coef != poly.h2l_end(); next_coef++)
        fx = gf255_mul(fx, x) ^ *next_coef; // Recall ^ is addition in GF 2^8

    return fx;
}
```

Simple though that seems, there's something going wrong with the types. Visual Studio gives me this error on the line with the for loop, which I can't seem to puzzle out:

```
error C2664: 'std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base>::_Revranit(_RanIt)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>' to 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>'
```

I don't understand this message - **I've provided methods that return both iterators and const_iterators. Why can't the compiler choose between them?**

---

Implicit in this question is whether this is a good strategy for hiding the details from the caller at all (since they still have to deal with these std::vector types), and I would appreciate answers that also address this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
charVec::reverse_iterator next_coef = poly.h2l_begin();
```

`next_coef` is a `reverse_iterator`.  What does `h2l_begin()` return?

Well, `poly` is a:

```
const gf255_poly &poly
```

a `const gf255_poly`.  So let us look at the overrides of `h2l_begin()`:

```
charVec::const_reverse_iterator h2l_begin() const { return p.rbegin(); };
charVec::reverse_iterator       h2l_begin() { return p.rbegin(); };
```

There are two overloads.  Only one is valid, because `poly` is `const`, and that is this one:

```
charVec::const_reverse_iterator h2l_begin() const { return p.rbegin(); };
```

so `poly.h2l_begin()` returns a `charVec::const_reverse_iterator`.

`charVec::const_reverse_iterator` cannot be converted to `charVec::reverse_iterator`, because `charVec::const_reverse_iterator` allows you to modify the thing being iterated over, while `charVec::reverse_iterator` does not.

In short, because `poly` is `const`, you have promised not to modify it.  And then you iterated it over it using types that could modify it.  So you get a type error.

Second, and as an aside, note that the compiler **never chooses between functions based on return type** (except arguably the conversion `operator T()`).  If you had a non-const `poly` stored it in a `const_reverse_iterator`, you'd still call the `reverse_iterator h2l_begin()`.  The `reverse_iterator` would just convert to a `const_reverse_iterator`.

---

First thing to do is to upgrade to C++11.  This is 2016.

Second, I'd write a `range_t<Iterator>` which stores a range of iterators and exposes `begin` and `end` and conditionally (based on random-access-ness of `Iterator` `operator[]`, `size`, etc.  Also `remove_front(size_t)` and `front()` and `empty` and ...

Then I'd write `array_view<T>:range_it<T*>` which represents a range of contiguous `T`s, with implicit ctors from containers with a `T* C::data()` method, raw C-arrays, and `T*, size_t`.

Finally, I'd write `backwards_t` and `backwards` function, which takes a `range_t<Iterator>` and returns a `range_t< reverse_iterator< Iterator > >`.

Now my `gf255_poly` has these:

```
backwards_t< array_view< unsigned char > > h2l();
backwards_t< array_view< unsigned char const > > h2l() const;
array_view< unsigned char > l2h();
array_view< unsigned char const > l2h() const;
```

We can expose typedefs for the iterators if we choose (and in C++03 we have little choice).

In C++11 it looks like:

```
for (auto&& next_coef = poly.h2l())
  fx = gf255_mul(fx, x) ^ next_coef; // Recall ^ is addition in GF 2^8
```

which is nice.

Comment: Unfortunately, C++11 isn't currently an option. The whole dev shop lives in hope of an upgrade to VS, but there's no indication it's actually going to happen. Still, thank you for a thorough answer and more ammunition to push for the new features!

Answer (score 1):

`poly` is a const object, so `h2l_begin()` will return a const_reverse_iterator.  You've declared `next_coef` as a `reverse_iterator`, and you can't assign a const iterator to an iterator.  Either change `next_coef` to be a `const_reverse_iterator`, or declare it in the for loop with auto.

```
for (auto next_coef = poly.h2l_begin(); next_coef != poly.h2l_end(); ++next_coef)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
charVec::reverse_iterator next_coef;
```

to this:

```
charVec::const_reverse_iterator next_coef;
```

You see: `poly` is a `const` reference to a `gf255_poly` object, meaning the request for `poly.h2l_begin();` will prefer the `const` qualified version of that function during overload resolution.

Better still, use `auto`

```
for (auto next_coef = poly.h2l_begin(); next_coef != poly.h2l_end(); next_coef++)
    fx = gf255_mul(fx, x) ^ *next_coef; // Recall ^ is addition in GF 2^8
```

If you must still keep the iterator outside the for loop initializer, you can move the intitialization outside:

```
auto next_coef = poly.h2l_begin()
for (; next_coef != poly.h2l_end(); next_coef++)
    fx = gf255_mul(fx, x) ^ *next_coef; // Recall ^ is addition in GF 2^8
```