# Avoiding repetition of const and non-const version of getters?

Tags: c++, c++11, getter, function-qualifier, explicit-object-parameter

```
struct BananaHolder
{
    vector<Banana>& getBananas();
    const vector<Banana>& getBananas() const;
};
```

My classes are cluttered with this kind of duplication.

Is there a cleaner, more elegant alternative?

Comment: Perhaps returning references all the time isn't really the best option.

Comment: In my situation it is required.

Comment: @AndyProwl alright. Could you copy-paste that into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: Did that :) Deleting my previous comment...

Comment: One could go Standard Library route and create a template method function which accept banana holders and takes bananas out of them (I refer to `std::data`, etc). Except standard ones use existing getters, your function has to be a friend. But for a member function-getter? Before C++23 there is no way and C++23 way looks odd to me.

Comment: You appear to overuse the getter antipattern or you abuse inheritance. It might be time for interface separation, composition, for use of mementos or commands. Something that reduces number of entry point in interface of single class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your class *has* to return references, and if it has to return a reference to a modifiable vector when invoked on a modifiable object, then I do not think there is a way to avoid the duplication - at least, not the duplicate declaration.

Notice, that some types of the Standard Library also suffer from the same problem. For instance, sequence containers such as `std::vector` have both a `const` and a non-`const` overload of `operator []`, `at()`, `back()`, `front()`, `data()`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In C++23, you can solve this issue with [explicit object parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Explicit_object_parameter) (aka deducing this):

```cpp
struct BananaHolder
{
    vector<Banana> m_bananas;
    
    // using abbreviated function templates
    auto& getBananas(this auto&& self) {
        return self.m_bananas;
    }
    
    // or more verbosely
    template <typename Self>
    auto& getBananas(this Self&& self) {
        return self.m_bananas;
    }
};
```

This not only covers `const BananaHolder` and `BananaHolder`, it covers all combinations of `const`, `volatile`, lvalue reference, and rvalue reference qualifications.

If you wanted to make full use of this, you would write:

```cpp
// to get the same behavior without templates, we would need 16 overloads
template <typename Self>
auto&& getBananas(this Self&& self) {
    // without std::forward, this would always return an lvalue reference 
    return std::forward<Self>(self).m_bananas;
}
```

---

Prior to C++23, there is no way to avoid having at least two member functions.
You would have to write two getter overloads like you did, for example.

For something more complicated than a getter, see [How do I remove code duplication between similar const and non-const member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/123758/5740428).