# Perfect forwarding to a member function of a data member?

Tags: c++, member, auto, forwarding, c++14

Consider a class that has a `private` `std::vector` data member:

```
class MyClass 
{
    private: 
        std::vector<double> _data;
    public:
        template <class... Args>
        /* something */ insert(Args&&... args) /* something */
        {
            return _data.insert(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
};
```

What is the correct syntax (using C++14 auto/variadic templates/forward...) to transfer a given function of `_data` to `MyClass` (for example `insert` here) and provide the same interface for the user?

Comment: You mean the return type of your `insert` wrapper? `decltype(auto)`

Comment: The `something` after the parameter-list is supposed to contain the correct cv- and ref-qualifiers and exception-specification?

Comment: "What is the correct syntax to transfer a given function of _data to MyClass" -> Erm, what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax is this:

```
class MyClass 
{
    private: 
        std::vector<double> _data;
    public:
        template <class... Args>
        decltype(auto) insert(Args&&... args)
        {
            return _data.insert(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
};
```

However, you don't actually need C++14 to do it. You can just use the C++11 syntax.

```
class MyClass 
{
    private: 
        std::vector<double> _data;
    public:
        template <class... Args>
        auto insert(Args&&... args) 
        -> decltype(_data.insert(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
        {
            return _data.insert(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
};
```

Comment: Or the regular C++: `std::vector::iterator insert(...)`

Comment: I think the OP wants the wrapper function to have the same exception-specification and cv-qualification too (and maybe ref-qualifiers, although that's not relevant for `std::vector`)

Comment: @JonathanWakely maybe one day we'll have `noexcept(auto)` :P

Answer (score 2):

To *truly* forward a call to a member function, one must consider the necessity of correctly forwarding the `*this` value for the member call.

The following:

```
template<typename Type>
struct Fwd {
    Type member;

    template<typename ...Args>
    decltype(auto) Func(Args&&... args)
        noexcept(noexcept(member.Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))
        { return member.Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
};
```

is sufficient for forwarding *arguments* and the exception specification, as you might have guessed. But it is insufficient to perfect forward `*this`:

```
struct S {
    // These overloads are reachable through Fwd<S>::Func().
    void Func(int) & {}
    void Func(int&&) & {}

    // These other overloads are not.
    void Func(int) const&;
    void Func(int&&) const&;
    void Func(int) volatile&;
    void Func(int&&) volatile&;
    void Func(int) const volatile&;
    void Func(int&&) const volatile&;
    void Func(int) &&;
    void Func(int&&) &&;
    // (These are rather uncommon, just provided for completude.)
    void Func(int) const&&;
    void Func(int&&) const&&;
    void Func(int) volatile&&;
    void Func(int&&) volatile&&;
    void Func(int) const volatile&&;
    void Func(int&&) const volatile&&;
};
```

There are two solutions for this problem. One is to simply create each and every other possible overload manually, possibly with a macro:

```
#define FWD(member, Func) \
    template<typename ...Args> \
    decltype(auto) Func(Args&&... args) & \
        noexcept(noexcept(member.Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) \
        { return member.Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); } \
    \
    template<typename ...Args> \
    decltype(auto) Func(Args&&... args) const& \
        noexcept(noexcept(member.Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) \
        { return member.Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); } \
    \
    template<typename ...Args> \
    decltype(auto) Func(Args&&... args) volatile& \
        noexcept(noexcept(member.Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) \
        { return member.Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); } \
    \
    template<typename ...Args> \
    decltype(auto) Func(Args&&... args) const volatile& \
        noexcept(noexcept(member.Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) \
        { return member.Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); } \
    \
    template<typename ...Args> \
    decltype(auto) Func(Args&&... args) && \
        noexcept(noexcept(member.Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) \
        { return std::move(member).Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); } \
    \
    template<typename ...Args> \
    decltype(auto) Func(Args&&... args) const&& \
        noexcept(noexcept(member.Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) \
        { return std::move(member).Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); } \
    \
    template<typename ...Args> \
    decltype(auto) Func(Args&&... args) volatile&& \
        noexcept(noexcept(member.Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) \
        { return std::move(member).Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); } \
    \
    template<typename ...Args> \
    decltype(auto) Func(Args&&... args) const volatile&& \
        noexcept(noexcept(member.Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) \
        { return std::move(member).Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

template<typename Type>
struct Fwd {
    Type member;
    FWD(member, Func)
};
```

The other solution is to avoid a member function altogether and use a free function:

```
template<typename Fwd, typename ...Args>
decltype(auto) Func(Fwd&& fwd, Args&&... args)
    noexcept(noexcept(std::forward<Fwd>(fwd).Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) {
    return std::forward<Fwd>(fwd).Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```