# is return *this safe in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I was wondering if returning *this from a function is safe. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919330/return-this-in-c) question shows some ways you can do it and my question is given this example:

```
struct test {
    string t;
    string b;
public:
    test& A(string test)       { this->t=test; return *this; }

    test& B(string test)       { this->b=test; return *this; }
};

int main() {

    auto a = test().A("a").B("b").A("new a");
    return 0;
}
```

Is there going to be memory leakage?

Comment: Which memory are you thinking may leak?

Comment: Why would there be any memory leak?  I see no allocation and no dangling pointers.

Comment: If you don't ask for any memory you can't leak it.

Comment: Certain operations, like `operator=` are **required** to return a reference to `*this`.  So yes, it is perfectly safe.  It is a form of [fluent-style coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: in the A() , B() and A().

Comment: Ive just never seen this kind of code in c++. Is it often used?

Comment: @JökullSnærGylfason: `A()` and `B()` are simply making copies of `std::string` objects. That memory is managed automatically, so there is no leaking. This type of chaining code is not *often* used, though a good example of it is STL I/O streams via `operator>>` and `operator<<` chaining, where a reference to the input stream is output in the return value.

Comment: Okey. then its safe, thank you for the fast respond. I needed to be certain :)

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429148/return-this-as-rvalue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is return `*this` safe in c++

Fundamentally yes, it is safe. In fact, it is a common pattern. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Of course it can also be misused:

```
auto& foo = test().A("a");
foo.B("b"); // oops, foo is a dangling reference
```

---

> my question is given this example:
>
> [snip]
>
> Is there going to be memory leakage?

No, there is no memory leakage in the shown code.