# Remove duplication between (non-)const member function returning a vector of pointers to (non-)const objects

Tags: c++, constants, stdvector, code-duplication, member-functions

I have two overloads of a member function:

```
const std::vector<Tile*>& Level::calculateTilesWithinAABB(const gm::AABB& Box)
{
    static std::vector<Tile*> Tiles;
    Tiles.clear();

    /* Calculations to add pointers to elements
       in member std::vector<Tile> to Tiles: */

    auto Pos = pxToGridPos(Box.getTopLeft());
    auto Top = pxToGridPos(Box.getTop());
    auto Right = pxToGridPos(Box.getRight());
    auto Bottom = pxToGridPos(Box.getBottom());

    for (; Pos.x <= Right; ++Pos.x)
        for (Pos.y = Top; Pos.y <= Bottom; ++Pos.y)
            if (Pos.x < mSize.x && Pos.y < mSize.y)
                Tiles.push_back(&getTileAtPos(Pos));

    return Tiles;
}

const std::vector<const Tile*>& Level::calculateTilesWithinAABB(const gm::AABB& Box) const
{
    static std::vector<const Tile*> Tiles;
    Tiles.clear();

    /* Same duplicated code. */

    return Tiles;
}
```

I want to remove the duplicate commented out code. How can it be done?

There's a related question, [How do I remove code duplication between similar const and non-const member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/123758/3425536), but the solution doesn't work in this case since you cannot cast between `std::vector<const T*>` and `std::vector<T*>`.

[Here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PD8krCgv91MdK7OF)'s a compilable version the above code for experimenting.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Make the duplicate code a macro, and use the macro in the two functions.
2. In the non-`const` version, use `reinterpret_cast` to cast from `std::vector<const Tile*>` to `std::vector<Tile*>`:

   ```
   return reinterpret_cast<const std::vector<Tile*>&>(
              const_cast<const Level*>(this)->calculateTilesWithinAABB(Box));
   ```

   which compiles and seems to work. But is it safe / guaranteed to work on all major compilers?

Comment: How significant is the duplicated code?  Is it something that could be macro-itized?.

Comment: 8 lines atm, but it might grow in the future. Yes, macro-itizing it would be one solution, not a particularly beautiful one though.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about your duplicated code? Which part exactly isn't compatible anymore? The a possible solution would range from auto code deduction to a templated method... it's very dependent on the duplicated code.

Comment: @DenisBlank Added the code to the question.

Comment: Why is the first member function non-const?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Because it returns pointers to non-const `Tile`s, that are part of the `Level` and modifying them should be considered a modification of the `Level`.