# Implement const and non-const version of methods taking a callback

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, const-cast

I have the following interface:

```
struct A {};

struct B
{
    using Cb = std::function<void(A& a)>;
    using ConstCb = std::function<void(const A& a)>;

    virtual void visit(ConstCb cb) const = 0;
    virtual void visit(Cb cb) = 0;
};
```

`B::visit()` shall enumerate all members of itself that are of type `A`.

Now, since B::visit() might become complex in deriving classes, so duplicating the implementation of `visit()` is not nice. Meyers advises const-casting (cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func)).

So an approach would be:

```
struct B
{
    using Cb = std::function<void(A& a)>;
    using ConstCb = std::function<void(const A& a)>;

    void visit(Cb cb);
    void visit(ConstCb cb) const;

protected:
    virtual void doVisit(ConstCb) const = 0;
};

void B::f(ConstCb cb) const
{
    doVisit(cb);
}

void B::f(Cb cb)
{
    static_cast<const B*>(this)->f(/* somehow cast cb to ConstCb */);
}
```

However, exactly that missing piece seems to be impossible. I can get a function pointer of `cb` using `std::function::target()` and then try to cast it to the other type. But this is impossible, since `target()` doesn't work for lambdas, they can't be converted to function pointers (only if they have an empty capture).

So I can't think of a solution right now. Does somebody have any ideas? Perhaps the whole approach is flawed already :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to introduce a "trampoline" function that does the conversion from non-`const` to `const`:

```
void B::f(Cb cb)
{
    ConstCb trampoline = [&cb] (const A& arg) {
        cb(const_cast<A&>(arg));
    };
    static_cast<const B*>(this)->f(trampoline);
}
```

In other words, rather than doing a cast on the *function*, just define a new function that performs a cast on the *argument*.