# Designing two equivalent member functions returning a const and a non-const pointer-to-member, respectively

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, overloading, member-functions

I have a class `A` and a member function `f`, that returns a pointer to
some contents of the instance

```
int* A::f() {
  // common code ...
  return &(this->some_container[some_index])
}
```

Now, I need an analogue function, which only returns a `const` pointer,
i.e.

```
const int* A::f_const() const {
  // exactly the same lengthy code ...
  return &(this->some_container[some_index]);
}
```

Note that, as the "lengthy code" does not change the instance of `A`,
this also makes the function `const` w.r.t. the instance (the second
`const` statement).

**My question:** Now I wonder if there is some solution to avoid the code
doubling, *without using a third function*.

On one hand, calling `f` inside `f_const` would be illegal, as `f` is not
`const` w.r.t. the owning instance. On the other hand, calling `f_const`
inside `f` would require to convert a `const` pointer to a non-`const`
pointer, which is also impossible.

Is there any elegant declaration method, to avoid code doubling?

As said, using a third function with the common functionality of `f` and
`f_const` is not an option here, as when applied for a large number of
functions, it would make the code less readable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove code duplication between similar const and non-const member functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func)

Comment: Why are you doing this?  One never ceases to wonder at the boundlessly inane C++ problems one encounters.  Dr. Stroustrup never intended for his "practical joke" of a "language" (just ask him) to serve as a basis for piddling philosophical arguments about what side effects of what mechanisms can result in such-and-such unexpected or unhoped-for semantics.  Of course, you could just copy the datum into a static scalar and return its address, which should remain rather constant :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to premise the answer it could depend on the particular context (for example the length-code of the functions, returned type, etc...).

In general, for my experiences, the most practical, even if maybe a little bit ugly, solution is the *[const cast operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast)*.

Just to implement the *const* method and get it with a conversion in the *non-const* other method. Something like:

```
const int* A::f_const() const {
  return &(this->some_container[some_index]);
}

int* A::f() {
  return const_cast<int*>(f_const());
}
```

This is usually safe because you're the designer of the class itself.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive answer. It seems the implementation of `f_const` misses a member. Should it simply be `this->f_const()` or does `this` also need to be casted somehow?

Comment: @flonk Sorry, I cannot understand what do you mean. May you try to explain it again and more?

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to express something which made no sense anyhow, your answer is perfectly fine :)