# Avoid code duplication by implementing two functions that differ by const

Tags: c++

I have a generic `Matrix` class, and I have two version of `operator()`,
a const method that returns a const reference to the index,
and a non-const method that returns a non const reference to the index (which allows me to change it.

I tried to use the non-const version by using const_cast and calling for the const version, but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{

    std::vector<T> _matrix;
    unsigned int _rows;
    unsigned int _cols;
 public:
    const T& operator()(unsigned int row, unsigned int col) const
    {
        return _matrix[col + (_cols * row)];
    }

    T& operator()(unsigned int row, unsigned int col)
    {
    return const_cast<T&>(static_cast<const Matrix*> (*this).operator(row, col));
    }
};
```

It doesn't allow me to add the (row, col) to the operator in the last line. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove code duplication between similar const and non-const member functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func)

Comment: Make a macro.  You still get code duplication, but you can hide 50% of it.

Comment: You avoid code duplication by adding twice as much code, and make it more complicated. Doesn't seem like a win to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, code duplication is the lesser of the two evils. Simply repeat the expression `_matrix[col + (_cols * row)]` in the non-`const` version. Don't fight the language.

To call the `const` version, you need to `const_cast` the `this` pointer. The expression you were after was `const_cast<T&>(const_cast<const Matrix*>(this)->operator()(row, col));` which is considerably more difficult to read and does contain an unnerving `const_cast`; twice.

Answer (score 4):

In my humble opinion this is not a case where you want to avoid code duplication. So I suggest the following:

```
const T& operator()(unsigned int row, unsigned int col) const {
  return _matrix[col + (_cols * row)];
}

T& operator()(unsigned int row, unsigned int col) {
  return _matrix[col + (_cols * row)];
}
```

It's also more readable than the version with the `const_cast` and potentially faster as you avoid an unnecessary stack frame.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

```
return const_cast<T&>(const_cast<const Matrix*>(this)->operator()(row, col));
```

Comment: Upvoted: you figured out the expression 2 minutes before I did.