# How do I remove code duplication between similar ref-qualified member functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, dry, code-duplication, ref-qualifier

Similarly to [How do I remove code duplication between similar const and non-const member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/123758/1896169), I want to remove the code duplication between nearly identical member functions, except for ref qualifiers.

Let's say I have a class that's something like this:

```
class MyStringBuilder
{
    std::string member;
public:
    // Other functions
    std::string create() const& {
        // Some work
        std::string result = member;
        // More work
        return result;
    }

    std::string create() && {
        // Some work
        std::string result = std::move(member);
        // More work
        return result;
    }
};
```

It's not inconceivable that we would want to do this for a builder object, as it saves a copy if we are done with the `MyStringBuilder`.

Except for where members are used, the code between the `const&` version and `&&` version are identical. The only difference between the two functions is that the `&&` version `std::move`s any members whenever they are referenced.

How can I avoid this code duplication?

Comment: If only we had the [deducing this](https://wg21.link/p0847) proposal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you can do is you can implement the logic in a non-member function and take the type of `*this` as a template parameter:

```
class MyStringBuilder
{
    std::string member;

    template<typename Self>
    static std::string create_impl(Self&& self) {
        // Some work
        std::string result = std::forward<Self>(self).member;
        // More work
        return result;
    }
public:
    // Other functions
    std::string create() const& {
        return create_impl(*this);
    }

    std::string create() && {
        return create_impl(std::move(*this));
    }
};
```