# How to provide const version of operator -> for a handle class

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload my operator-> for a handle class to return const and non const pointer, pointing towards a base class.

Looking at the code i posted, in the trial function, if i add in the const keyword, the error message will be

```
||=== Build: Debug in Const trial (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Const trial\main.cpp
||In function 'bool trial(Cards_pointer)':|
C:\Const trial\main.cpp|50|error: passing 'const Cards_pointer' as 'this' argument of 'Cards*& Cards_pointer::operator->()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

My question is whether it is possible to do so, if yes, may i know what is the correct implementation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<stdexcept>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Cards
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    Cards():x(3) {}
    int rx()const
    {
        return x;
    }
};

class Cards_pointer
{
private:
    Cards* cp;
    size_t* refptr;

public:
//default constructor
    Cards_pointer():cp(0),refptr(new size_t(1)) {}
    Cards_pointer(Cards*t):cp(t),refptr(new size_t(1)) {}
//copy constructor
    Cards_pointer (const Cards_pointer&s):cp(s.cp),refptr(s.refptr)
    {
        refptr=s.refptr;
        cp=s.cp;
//++*refptr;
        *refptr=*refptr+1;
    }

    Cards*&operator->()
    {
        if(cp)
            return cp;

        else throw std::runtime_error("uninitialized Cards");
    }

};

bool trial(const Cards_pointer x)
{
    if(x->rx()==3)
        return true;

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    Cards_pointer x=new Cards();

    bool cond=trial(x);

}
```

Comment: Note that usually `operator->` returns  pointer, not a reference to a pointer.

Comment: So does it means i have to define another operator to return a const pointer?

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to do it anyway.

Comment: That is, if the "handled" object is conceptually part of the handle class. i.e. does modifying the handled object mean modifying the handle? This is a design choice. If the answer is no, then you just need `Cards* operator->() const`. If yes, you need two operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return a pointer to const and provide a const qualified overload

```
class Something {
public:
    void bar() {}
    void foo() const {}
};

class Wrapper {
public:
    Something* operator->() {
        return &this->something;
    }
    const Something* operator->() const {
        return &this->something;
    }
private:
    Something something;
};

int main() {
    const auto c_wrapper = Wrapper{};
    c_wrapper->foo();
    // The below is an error
    // c_wrapper->bar();
    auto m_wrapper = Wrapper{};
    m_wrapper->bar();
}
```

If you are worried about duplicated code in the const and non const overloads see [Const function calling non const or vice versa (to avoid duplication)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44755608/const-function-calling-non-const-or-vice-versa-to-avoid-duplication/44755654#44755654)

Comment: Hey, i have actually tried a similar function, however mine did not work  because i added & in between Something* and operator-> for the const version.. May i know why does that lead to an error?  The error message is as below C:\Const trial 2\main.cpp|18|error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const Something*&' from expression of type 'Something* const'|

Comment: Wrapper wraps a non-pointer. The example doesn't translate to smart pointers, which is what `Cards_pointer` meant to be.

Comment: @Esther I'm guessing thats the same reason this causes an error https://wandbox.org/permlink/Zi6o2PfpOSACKLq6

Answer (score 0):

If you overload your `operator->`, the behaviour will not mimick that of built-in pointers (and will not make much sense at all).

Built-in pointers come in two flavours: pointers and pointers-to-const. (We ignore volatile here). These flavours are *different* types. Pointers themselves being const have nothing to do with constness of what they point to.

In order to imitate this behaviour, you need two flavours of Cards_pointer, one with `operator->` that returns a normal pointer, and one with `operator->` that returns a pointer-to-const.

```
  class Cards_pointer_base { ... };
  class Cards_pointer: private Cards_pointer_base {         
     public:
       // usual constructors/assignment operators
       using ...; // necessary members from the base
       Cards* operator->() { ... }
  };
  class Cards_const_pointer: private Cards_pointer_base {         
     public:
       // usual constructors/assignment operators
       using ...; // necessary members from the base
       const Cards* operator->() { ... }
       // conversions from pointer to non-const
       Cards_const_pointer(const Cards_pointer& from) { ... }
       Cards_const_pointer& operator=(const Cards_pointer& from) { ... }
  };
```

Standard smart pointers are class templates, so one can just write `shared_ptr<Cards>` and `shared_ptr<const Cards>`.