# Non-const calling const member function fails with read-only location C++

Tags: c++, constants

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func) I implemented an accessor like

```
template<class T> class qv {
  virtual const T& operator[](int i) const = 0;
  T& operator[](int i) { return const_cast<T&>(static_cast<const qv*>(this)->operator[](i)); }
};
template<class T> class qq : public qv<T> {
 public:
  const T& operator[](int i) const override { return this->data[i]; }
 protected:
  T data[5];
};
```

but get an `assignment of read-only location` when trying to do something like:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  qq<int> q;
  q[3] = 2; // read-only location compile error, g++ 6.3
}
```

It's something with the inheritance that's causing issues but I don't know what or why. As an aside does it matter if I use a static or const_cast for the inner cast above?

Comment: Is `f` a `const` object? Then the `const` qualified `get` function will always be called. Please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and **Verifiable** Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `operator[]` declared in derived class *hides* the one in the base class. So `qv<T>::operator[]` can't be found in [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup).

(emphasis mine)

> name lookup examines the scopes as described below, until it finds at least one declaration of any kind, **at which time the lookup stops and no further scopes are examined**.

You could add `using qv<T>::operator[];` to introduce the name `operator[]` into the derived class. e.g.

```
template<class T> class qq : public qv<T> {
 public:
  using qv<T>::operator[];
  const T& operator[](int i) const override { return this->data[i]; }
 protected:
  T data[5];
};
```

BTW: I suppose that it's a typo to declare `qv<T>::operator[]` as `private`.

Comment: interesting. the feature of hiding the non-const version with a const version explicitly overriding seems pretty silly. don't know who would want that. oh well.

Comment: @user2183336 it is really no different from any other hiding. A single **name** introduced in derived class hides all **names** in the base class but the one introduced.

Comment: @user2183336 It's just how name lookup rule works. Answer edited.