# use templates to generate const and non-const identical methods?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to define an [interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface-based_programming) such as:

```
class IFoo
{
  virtual void foo(const X &x) const = 0;
  virtual void foo(X &x) = 0;
};
```

and define both `foo` methods in a subclass `C` with a template which can be instantiated twice, once for type argument `<const X>` and once for `<X>`? e.g something like:

```
class C : public IFoo
{
  template<typename T>
  void foo(T &t) {...}
};

// instantiate void C::foo(X &x)
//         and void C::foo(const X &x) const ???
```

Comment: Not directly, but if the template has a different name, then the implementation can implement the overrides with a single line each.

Comment: If you only have const and non-const, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/123758/1896169

Comment: Somewhat unusual way of dealing with such issues: if methods seems to be identical except for `const` qualifiers they are actually fundamentally different. That is they deserve different names and separate independent implementations. Even if their implementations happen to be identical it would be just a coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

Template functions cannot be virtual, so even if you were able to apply const-ness according to the template parameter, you would not be overriding the virtual functions. For example, the following fails to compile on g++ (4.8.5) with: `error: templates may not be ‘virtual’`

```
#include <iostream>

class IFoo
{
  virtual void foo(int &x) = 0;
};

class C : public IFoo
{
  template<typename T>
  virtual void foo(T &t) override {
    std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  C c;
  c.foo(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, it isn't possible. C++ allows to specify `noexcept` with additional compile time bool conditional, but this is sadly not true for `const`. Having an option to specify

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T &t) const(std::is_const_v<T>)
{
}
```

would be nice.