# Understanding const_cast in C++

Tags: c++, casting

I am trying to to understand `const_cast`.

In the example below, `items_` is a private member variable.

The method `getItems()` is a `const` method, which means that it cannot modify the member variable `items_`.

`getItems()` returns a `const vector` reference which means that you cannot modify the member variable `items_`.

My question is, is `const_cast` necessary here? I don't think so as I don't need to cast away constness?

```
#include <iostream>

class test {  
  std::vector<Item> items_;
public:
  const std::vector<Item>& getItems() const;
};

const std::vector<mv::Item>& mv::Workloads::getItems() const
{
  return const_cast<std::vector<Item>&>(items_);
}
```

Comment: *"which means that it cannot modify the member variable items_"* - it does not mean that. `const_cast` here makes no sense because you first remove `const` qualifier from reference but then immediately add it back when returning that reference from function.

Comment: I didnt really understand why you think the cast is needed, please eloborate, if the answer does not yet convince you

Comment: @VTT: _"'which means that it cannot modify the member variable items' - it does not mean that"_ That's exactly what it means. A member function qualified with `const` has only `const` access to data members.

Answer (score 5):

It is not only unnecessary but it is plain wrong in that place.

Consider what happens when you remove the `const` from the return type:

```
/*const*/ std::vector<mv::Item>& mv::Workloads::getItems() const
{
return const_cast<std::vector<Item>&>(items_);
}
```

Now the method returns a non-const reference to a `const` object! Note that the method itself is declared as `const`, hence `this` is `const` in the context of this method and also `items_` is `const`. Using the reference returned by that method would lead to undefined behaviour when the method is called on a `const test` instance.

In that sense, the only effect of the `const_cast` here is to potentially silence an important compiler error should you ever decide to change the return type.

On the other hand, in the method as is (ie returning a `const` reference) there is no reason for the cast. `items_` is `const` and a `const` reference to it is returned.

`const_cast` is useful eg to avoid code duplication for `const` and non-`const` methods when you do know for sure that the object you cast `const` away really is not `const`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func/123995) for details.

**PS**: in case you actually do want to return a mutable reference to a member from a `const` method, you would declare the member `mutable`. Also then no `const_cast` would be required. Though, `mutable` should be used with care and usually isnt needed in the first place.

Comment: If it's really necessary for a `const` member function to return a non-`const` reference to a member, then that member can be made `mutable`.   No need to muck around with `const_cast` at all - and it reduces the risk of introducing undefined behaviour.    Of course, the circumstances where it makes sense to return a non-`const` reference to a member from a `const` function are pretty uncommon in practice.

Comment: @Peter yes, the example is rather contrived, and `mutable` would be the way to go, no reason for `const_cast`, no risk of ub, though the question wasnt really about how to return a mutable ref from a `const` method, so I didnt go into more detail in the answer

Comment: @Peter added a PS to clarify

Answer (score 3):

It is not neccessary, simply return the `_items`.

Const member functions see the the object itself (`*this`) as const, so every data member is seen as const, from which building and returning const reference is allowed.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class test {

std::vector<Item> items_;
public:
const std::vector<Item>& getItems() const;
};
const std::vector<mv::Item>& mv::Workloads::getItems() const
{
return items_;
}
```

Comment: Furthermore, binding a const reference to a non const object would also be allowed, so it doesn't really matter whether the object is const or not.