# Seemingly missing optimization for calling const-vector size() in loop condition

Tags: c++, loops, optimization, vector, constants

Consider the following code:

```
int g(std::vector<int>&, size_t);

int f(std::vector<int>& v) {
   int res = 0;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
      res += g(v, i);
   return res;
}
```

The compiler cannot optimize away the evaluation of `v.size()` within the loop, since it cannot prove that the size won't change inside `g`. The assembly generated with GCC 9.2, `-O3`, and x64 is:

```
.L3:
    mov     rsi, rbx
    mov     rdi, rbp
    add     rbx, 1
    call    g(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, unsigned long)
    add     r12d, eax
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp+8] // load a poniter
    sub     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp+0] // subtract another pointetr
    sar     rax, 2                 // result * sizeof(int) => size()
    cmp     rbx, rax
    jb      .L3
```

If we know that `g` does not alter `v.size()`, we can rewrite the loop as follows:

```
for (size_t i = 0, e = v.size(); i < e; i++)
   res += g(v);
```

This generates simpler (and thus faster) assembly without those `mov`, `sub`, and `sar` instructions. The value of `size()` is simply kept in a register.

I would expect that the same effect could be achieved by making the vector `const` (I know it's changing the semantics of the program since `g` now cannot alter vector's elements, but this should be irrelevant to the question):

```
int g(const std::vector<int>&, size_t);

int f(const std::vector<int>& v) {
   int res = 0;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
      res += g(v, i);
   return res;
}
```

Now, the compiler should know that those pointers loaded in each loop iteration cannot change and, therefore, that the result of

```
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp+8] 
    sub     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp+0] 
    sar     rax, 2
```

is always the same. Despite that, these instructions **are present** in the generated assembly; live demo is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/jeTihg).

I have also tried Intel 19, Clang 9, and MSVC 19 with the very same results. Since all the mainstream compilers behave in such a uniform way, **I wonder whether there is some rule that disallows this kind of optimization, i.e., moving the evaluation of `size()` for a constant vector out of the loop**.

Comment: And wouldn't it be faster using iterators?

Comment: @slepic This very much depends on the operations performed inside the loop. For instance, in my (academic) case, `g` requires and index as a second argument. Another case generally complicated for iterators is when you need to access multiple vector elements in each iteration.

Comment: But that should not be a problem. `res=0; i=0; for(auto& val : v) {res+=g(val,v,i); ++i;}`

Comment: or another solution would be to just move the size evaluation out of the loop condition explicitly. `auto size=v.size(); for(size_t i=0; i<size; ++i)`

Comment: @slepic That's what my second loop version does. However, the question is not about how to iterate over vector elements. The question is about seemingly (for me) missing optimizations. I may easily come up with a use case where there is no loop at all. Such as `v.size(); g(v); v.size();` — can `v.size()` be evaluated only once? The same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `const` does not mean that `g` cannot change the size of the vector. Sadly.

You get UB if you modify an object that is itself `const`. Modifying an object to which you have a `const` reference is not UB, as long as the original (i.e. referenced) object is not `const`.

In other words, this is a valid program:

```
int g(const std::vector<int>& v, size_t)
{
    const_cast<std::vector<int>&>(v).clear();
    return 0;
}

int f(const std::vector<int>& v) {
   int res = 0;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
      res += g(v, i);
   return res;
}

void test()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    f(v);
}
```

---

Note that, if we cannot see the definition of `g`, the `const` doesn't even matter even if we disallowed `const_cast`:

```
std::vector<int> global_v;

int g(const std::vector<int>& v, size_t)
{
    global_v.clear();
    return 0;
}

int f(const std::vector<int>& v) {
   int res = 0;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
      res += g(v, i);
   return res;
}

void test()
{
    f(global_v);
}
```

Consider `const` on references as a reminder and compiler-enforced safeguard for yourself (and others), but not so much as an optimization opportunity for the compiler. However, marking values/objects as `const` themselves has decent chances of improving optimizations - passing an actual `const Something` to an opaque function guarantees that `Something` holds the same thing afterwards (but note that `const` is not transitive through e.g. pointer or reference members).

Comment: Ty, I didn't know that a non-const object bound to a const reference may be modified via `const_cast` applied to that reference. That explains it perfectly, and I did learn something new today :)

Comment: @bartop To learn something that shouldn't be used is very usefull ;)

Comment: @bartop There are fringe cases where it makes sense to use it. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func. I'd prefer a higher level way to avoid code duplication between const/non-const member function pairs (e.g. similar to template noexcept stuff) but this is what we have for now.

Comment: @bartop I (and Daniel, I guess) thought that you were referring to `const_cast`, not global mutable state, when you said "should not be used". It's ambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

Sad truth is `const` in function parameters is not that useful for optimization. Imagine code like this (I know it is not good practice and so forth but for the sake of argument):

```
int g(const std::vector<int>&v){
    const_cast<std::vector<int> &>(v).push_back(1);
    return 0;
}

int f(const std::vector<int>& v) {
   int res = 0;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
      res += g(v);
   return res;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
    return f(v);
}
```

If vector passed to `f` is not `const` itself, this is legal code.