# Same template specialization for const & non const type

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I have a following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{};

class B
{};

template<typename T>
void Do(T data)
{
    std::cout << "Do() default\n";
}

template<>
void Do(A* data)
{
    std::cout << "Do(A*)\n";
}

template<>
void Do(B* data)
{
    std::cout << "Do(B*)\n";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A* a = nullptr;
    B* b = nullptr;

    const A* aConst = nullptr;
    const B* bConst = nullptr;

    Do(a);
    Do(aConst);

    Do(b);
    Do(bConst);

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
Do(A*)
Do() default
Do(B*)
Do() default
```

How should I rewrite the code to share template specialization for const & non-const type without copy pasting the specialization with const keyword specifier so it produces output:

```
Do(A*)
Do(A*)
Do(B*)
Do(B*)
```

Comment: `template<>void Do(A* data)` calling `template<>void Do(const A* data)` ? Or do you want to avoid even the intermediate call?

Comment: In case you go with overloads instead of specialization, a related and very common problem is code reuse for const/non-const _member_ functions. There are different solutions to that one, which can also be applied to const-qualified parameters in general. I proposed mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56694496/5427663]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## C++14

I upvoted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58633909/5427663) which is a good showcase for SFINAE. To extend on it, you can simplify the SFINAE expression with `std::is_convertible`. This is more analogous how overload resolution would work (adding const qualifier).

```cpp
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T*, const A*>, int> = 0>
void Do(T* data)
{
    std::cout << "Do(A*)\n";
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T*, const B*>, int> = 0>
void Do(T* data)
{
    std::cout << "Do(B*)\n";
}
```

---

## C++17

As a bonus, in C++17 with `constexpr if`, you can use a single function for all cases:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void Do(T data)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<T, const A*>)
        std::cout << "Do(A*)\n";
    else if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<T, const B*>)
        std::cout << "Do(B*)\n";
    else    
        std::cout << "Do() default\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of specializing, you can overload.  Using

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, A>, bool> = true>
void Do(T* data)
{
    std::cout << "Do(A*)\n";
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, B>, bool> = true>
void Do(T* data)
{
    std::cout << "Do(B*)\n";
}
```

These functions will be called when you pass `const A*`/`A*`/`const B*`/`B*` since they are a better match then the generic template.  The reason they are a better match is because `T` is more constrained.  It is considered *more specialized* and so it will win in a tie breaker with the generic template in overload resolution.

Comment: I like the new name.

Comment: this is basically what i was looking for, thanks. You missed couple of typename's tho.

Comment: @mezo The typenames aren't required when using `enable_if_t`.  If I was using `std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, A>, bool>::type` then I would since `::type` is a dependent type.

Comment: See the code working here without them: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94b0b64bfc0039af

Answer (score 0):

You could use this pattern, if you are willing to write a small stub:

```
template<>
void Do(const A* data)
{
    std::cout << "Do(A*)\n";
}

template<>
void Do(A* data)
{
    Do((const A*)data);
}
```

The main code you don't want to duplicate uses `const A*`, because, well, you want it to work on const data too. The non-const one simply forward to it.