# C++ std::unordered_set find/count/contains const key reference

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, std

I have a `std::unordered_set<int *>` (in my real code I use pointers to a class, but `int *` works for this example too) and want to check whether a given pointer is stored in that set. Since the function `contains` will only be available for C++20, I'm using the function [`size_type count( const Key& key ) const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/count).

If I'm now searching for a const pointer instead of a pointer, the compilation fails with the message `error: invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘std::unordered_set<int*>::key_type {aka int*}’ [-fpermissive]`

Example code:

```cpp
#include <unordered_set>

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<int *> set {};

    int foo = 42;
    set.insert(&foo);

    int *pointer = &foo;
    set.count(pointer); // works fine

    const int *const_pointer = pointer;
    set.count(const_pointer); // doesn't work
    set.count(const_cast<int *>(const_pointer)); // works fine

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using `g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0` with C++11.

Is there a way to avoid that ugly `const_cast<>`? That error seems quite unimportant to me...

Comment: Do you know the difference between `const int *` and `int * const`? In your example `const_pointer` is not a constant pointer, but a pointer to a constant.

Comment: As the pointer won't be used for anything other than comparison I'd say that `const_cast` is valid in this case and not "ugly". Maybe you can create your own `contains` for your specific set that takes a const pointer and does the cast inside?

Comment: @Brian yes, I know the difference. Probably the wording was a bit bad in this question... adding a `const` behind that `*` doesn't change the behavior (it is added implicitly in the function call anyway)

Comment: @simon A contains function wouldn't really make sense in my case because I want to use that in a function called `isConnected(const Node *const otherNode) { return ...;}` and is in that sense already the wrapper itself :D  considering the const_cast as valid is totally fine, although I want to avoid it (I'm quite new to C++, only about 2 weeks, used mainly Java before)

Comment: Can you change the set to `std::unordered_set<int const*> set {};`?

Comment: Then I suggest that you just use the `const_cast`. If you still think that it looks odd, just add a comment to explain why it's used and/or a link to somewhere (maybe this question) that explains it. I have a few comments with this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/123995/969365 in my code where I use that solution

Comment: @Eljay in this example yes and the error is gone then, but not in my real code. It's probably best to tolerate that `const_cast`

Comment: In your real code, can you overload `bool isConnected(Node* otherNode) const` and `bool isConnected(Node const* otherNode) const`, and have the latter do the `const_cast` to the former?  That'll make the callsites cleaner, and sweep the ugly under the rug.

Comment: Even in C++20, I think you would need to set up "transparent" hash and equality functor types to use either `contains` or `count`, instead of using default template arguments `std::hash<int*>` and `std::equal_to<int*>`.

Comment: @Eljay for the caller side I used all possible const values and there is exactly one version of the function (my previous comment missed a const after the argument list and I don't find the edit button...). Adding an additional non-const function would be non-sense. I consider this as closed (I should be able to close my own post...) and stick to the `const_cast`

Comment: You will still have to do `const_cast` even if you plan to use [contains](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/contains) from C++20.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of C++, in my opinion.

Although there is clearly a trivial equality comparison between an `int*` and a `const int*`, the machinery of an associative container doesn't "know" that, unless you set up a [transparent comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20317413/4386278) for your map.

For an unordered associative container like yours, you'd also need a transparent hash (similar principle).

In this case, to be honest, and for simplicity, I'd just stick with the `const_cast`.