# Using non-const reference as const in C++

Tags: c++, constants

I'm trying to use *const* keyword correctly in my code.
I have a class *A* that have some other classes *B* in and *std::array* as member variable.

I have an accessor to get one of *A*'s *B* member.

```
  class B
  {
    public:
      int getMember() const;
  };


  class A
  {
    public:
      B& getB(const size_t idx)
      {
        return m_bCollection[idx];
      }

    private:
      std::array<B, 10> m_bCollection;
  };
```

Then I added a function to serialize an instance of A for yaml-cpp

```
  YAML::Emitter& operator<<(YAML::Emitter& out, const A& a)
  {
    // some stuff here, and then:
    out << a.getB(1).getMember();

    return out;
  }
```

This does not compile since the call to *getB* violates the *const* modifier for *a* argument of my
serializing function.

> error: passing ‘const A’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers

I could overload my *getB* method to have a constant version of it, but this does not seems very
clean...

```
  B& A::getB(const size_t idx);
  const B& A::getB(const size_t idx) const;
```

I have this issue on other similar classes as well and have const-overloaded a lot more method.
This modification seems a mess to me.
I think I missed a cleaner way to achieve my goal (having a *const A&* as serializer argument).

I only use const members of the non-const *B* instance reference returned by the const *A* instance.
What should I refactor here to have clean code that follow c++ good practices ?

Comment: `const B& A::getB(const size_t idx) const;`is the right way, the more you can put your members `const `the better it is. Note you can also have a `const` and a non `const` version of your members

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func) should be helping. It's also an item in Effective C++. Casting argument to const and cast away return value with const_cast is okay.

Comment: Having both `const` and not `const` overload *is* clean C++.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove code duplication between similar const and non-const member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func)

Answer (score 2):

> I only use const members of the non-const B instance reference returned by the const A instance. What should I refactor here to have clean code that follow c++ good practices ?

The clean idomatic way is the one that you do not want because you consider it as messy. Your `A` should look like this

```
class A
  {
    public:
      B& getB(size_t idx)    
      {
        return m_bCollection[idx];
      }
      const B& getB(size_t idx) const {
        return m_bCollection[idx];
      }   
    private:
      std::array<B, 10> m_bCollection;
  };
```

To avoid code duplication you can use the solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47369227/4117728) or other answers of that question.

In general you should make methods that do not modify members `const` by default. Only if you need them non-const supply a second overload (not the other way around). There will be many more cases where you will hit the same wall with your code. Just as one example, an overload for `operator<<` should have this signature:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const A&); 
                                       // ^--------  const !!!
```

Last but not least: I suppose it is due to simplification of your example, but your `getA` looks like an attempt for encapsulation. In fact it is not. Once you returned a non-const reference to a member you can make the member `public` as well. The only purpose `getB` serves is that you can write `a.getB(index)` instead of `a.m_bCollection[index]` but it does not achieve encapsulation.

Comment: I don't see how it's "dirty and hacky", at least not any more than having to copy and paste... In C++17 it already looks a lot better, and one can add a quick helper function to make it look better still: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47369227/2757035

Comment: @underscore_d it was more hacky in my memory ;). Fixed that part