# Copy paste of const and non-const methods

Tags: c++, c++14

Consider the following code:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d89377889a8ff749

IStorage has const and non-const get methods.
The concrete implementation defines them, but the definition is just copy-paste. 
I could not call one get method from another because of the const mechanics of C++.

Is there any way to avoid this copy-paste?

Comment: dupe of [How do I remove code duplication between similar const and non-const member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func) (also, please post code in the q, not linked externally)

Comment: Yep, that is the dupe. Is there any way to remove this question? I can not see the button.

Comment: If two more users mark it as a duplicate, it'll be closed as such, otherwise there might be a "Delete" link under your question, although I don't think it'll work as someone has answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the legitmate uses of `const_cast`

```
const std::string* get(ID id) const override
{
    return const_cast<ConcreteStorage*>(this)->get(id);
}
```