# can I override c++ operator[] with only one function?

Tags: c++, constants, overriding, operator-keyword

I have a code that works like this:

```
template<size_t size>
struct myClass {
public:
    std::array<uint8_t, size> bytes;

    bool operator==(const myClass<size>& o) const {
        for (size_t i{0}; i < size; ++i) {
            if (bytes[i] != o.bytes[i]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    uint8_t& operator[] (size_t ind) {
        return bytes[ind];
    }

    const uint8_t& operator[] (size_t ind) const { 
        return bytes[ind]; // function body is identical, can I write only once?
    }
};

int main() {

    myClass<4> my{23,24,55,26};
    my.bytes[2] = 24;
    cout << std::dec << static_cast<int32_t>(my[2]) << endl;
    my[2] = 44;
    cout << static_cast<int32_t>(my[2]) << endl;

    uint8_t *p1 = &my[2];
    cout << static_cast<int32_t>(*p1) << endl;

    const myClass<4> my2{23,24,55,26};
    const uint8_t *p2 = &my2[2];
    cout << static_cast<int32_t>(*p2++) << endl;
    cout << static_cast<int32_t>(*p2) << endl;

return 0;}
```

My question is that, the `uint8_t& operator[](size_t ind){}` and `const uint8_t& operator[](size_t ind) const {}` have identical function body of `return bytes[ind];`. Therefore, I need to write identical code for two times. Is there a method that I only write the function body for once, and also make the code work?

Comment: [How do I remove code duplication between similar const and non-const member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func)

Comment: In short, with C++23, yes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69486322